# Can boolean variables be used to generate random numbers?

Tags: c

I was playing around with bool variables. I am aware that boolean is used to represent a true (any other number besides 0) or false (the number 0). I realized that the variables create random integer numbers. I was wondering if one can one use boolean variables to generate random numbers? Can someone please elaborate on this behaviour caused by the keyword boolean?

My code is as follows:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
  #include<stdbool.h>

  int main()
 {
  bool a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k;

   printf("%d\n",a);
   printf("%d\n",b);
   printf("%d\n",c);
   printf("%d\n",d);
   printf("%d\n",e);
   printf("%d\n",f);
   printf("%d\n",g);
   printf("%d\n",h);
   printf("%d\n",i);
   printf("%d\n",j);
   printf("%d\n",k);
 }
```

Answer (score 4):

This is not behaviour specific to a bool. This is caused because you are using an [uninitialized variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15268799/uninitialized-variable-in-c). This is not only not random, it is not safe. This is [**undefined behaviour**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub), you should avoid it at all costs.

Comment: Per the C standard, the values of uninitialized objects are indeterminate. This does not necessarily lead to undefined behavior.

Comment: For example, `unsigned char x; printf("%d %d", x, x);` must print the same number twice. If the behavior were undefined according to the C standard, this could print two different values or crash. But the behavior is not undefined; it behaves as if `x` has some value.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Do you have the reference? I thought it was undefined, same as the c++ standard?

Comment: C 2011 [N1570] 6.7.9 10 says that uninitialized objects with automatic storage duration have indeterminate values. But I had forgotten 6.3.2.1 2, which says, if the address of the object is not taken, the behavior is undefined. Thus, inserting an otherwise unused `&x;` suffices to make the behavior defined, since it takes the address of `x`.

Answer (score 0):

Boolean is not randomly defined. These variables take `false` as  default value. In compiler. The default value is consistent rather than random 0 or 1 from time to time.

Comment: Actually they do not take any value as a default value. In most implementations it is whatever the value is in the memory where the bool is made. It could be 0 or anything else. It is only set to a default when it is declared global or static.

Comment: I think they do, maybe some languages do have 0 to anything, but some only do have 0 and 1,  VB has a boolean value of 0 and 1. If you consider SQL Server's bit as a boolean value, it also has 0 and 1

Comment: Per C 2011 (N1570) 6.7.9 10: “If an object that has automatic storage duration is not initialized explicitly, its value is indeterminate.”