# Why prinf prints random number?

Tags: c, integer, initialization, printf, undefined-behavior

This is my code. Why does C prints a random number like 3321856?
I know it's because it's an empty variable, but why this number? is it random or has some reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    int a;
    printf("%d", a);
}
```

Comment: `a` isn't initialized to anything, so its value is indeterminate.

Comment: What did you expect to be printed, and why?

Comment: Why this number? Is it a random number?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why default value of local variables in C is same?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17392364/why-default-value-of-local-variables-in-c-is-same)

Comment: Formally, it's indeterminate.  In practice, it may be the contents of a register or memory location left over from some previous operation.  It may or may not be hard to predict its value, depending on how much you know about the program and how it was compiled.  It is certainly not random in any useful probabilistic sense.

Comment: The best remedy is to always enable compiler warnings and treat warnings as errors. Then it doesn't matter what value uninitialised variables can get.

Comment: `a` should have been the random number [nine](https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25). 
 

Comment: Note that `3321856` is `0x32_B000`, perhaps not so _random_,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters, the function main without parameters according to the C Standard shall be declared as follows.

```
int main( void )
```

Secondly, the variable `a` is not initialized and has an indeterminate value, so the program invokes undefined behavior.

You need to initialize the variable `a` with a value before outputting that value, or the output will be undefined.

The variable `a` is defined in the outer block scope of the function main without the storage class specifier `static`. So it has automatic storage duration. Such variables are not implicitly initialized.

Comment: Is it a random number?

Comment: @איתמרשיאון It outputs anything that is in the memory occupied by the variable a.