# Clarifying How Bitwise Operators, Non-Negative Operants, and Type Conversion Interact

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, language-lawyer

## Question

As a fledgling C language-lawyer, I have run into a situation where I am uncertain if I understand what C specifications logically guarantee correctly.

As I understand it, "bitwise operators" (`&`, `|`, and `&`) will work as intuitively expected on **non-negative** values with any of C's *integer types* (`char`/`short`/`int`/`long`/etc, whether `signed` or `unsigned`) - regardless of underlying object representation.

Is this correct understanding of what is/isn't strictly well-defined behavior in C?

## Key Point

In many ways, this question boils down to whether a conforming implementation is allowed to take two non-trap, non-negative values as operands to the bitwise operators, and produce a trap representation result (from the operation itself, not from assigning/interpreting the result into/as an inappropriate type).

## Example

Consider the following code:

```
#include <limits.h>
#define MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT = (unsigned char )((UCHAR_MAX >> 1) + 1)

/* ... in some function: */

unsigned char byte;
/* Using broad meaning of "byte", not necessarily "octet" */
int val;

/* val is assigned an arbitrary _non-negative_ value at runtime */

byte = val | MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT;
```

Do note the above comment that `val` receives a **non-negative** value at runtime (which can be represented by `val`'s type).

My expectation is that `byte` has the most significant bit set, and the lower bits are the pure binary representation (no padding bits or trap representations) of the bottom `CHAR_BIT - 1` bits of the *numerical value* of `val`.

I expect this to remain true even if the type of `val` is changed to any other integer type, but I expect this guarantee to disappear as soon as the value of `val` becomes negative (no one result guaranteed for all implementations), or the type of `val` is changed to any non-integer type (violates a constraint of C's definition of the bitwise operators).

## Self-Answering

I am posting my explanation of my current understanding as an answer because I'm fairly confident in it, but I am looking for corrections to any of my misconceptions and will accept any better/correcting answer instead of mine.

Answer (score 2):

## Why (I Think) This Is (Probably) Correct

The bitwise operators `&`, `|`, and `^` are defined as operating on the actual binary representation of the *converted operands*: the operands are said to undergo the "usual arithmetic conversions".

As I understand it, it logically follows that when you use two integer type expressions with non-negative values as operands to one of those operators, regardless of padding bits or trap representations, their value bits will "line up": therefore, the result's *value bits* will have the numerical value which matches with what you'd expect if you just assumed a "pure binary representation".

The kicker is that so long as you start with valid (non-trap), non-negative values as the operands, the operands should always promote to an integer type which can represent both of their values, and thus can logically represent the result value for either of those three operations. You also never run into possible issues with e.g. "signed zero", because limiting yourself to non-negative values avoids such problems. And so long as the result is used as a type which can hold the result value (or as an unsigned integer type), you won't introduce other similar/related issues.

#### Can These Operations Produce A Trap Representation From Non-Negative Non-Trap Operands?

Footnotes 44/53 and 45/54 of the last C99/C11 drafts, respectively, seem to suggest that the answer to this uncertainty depends on whether `foo | bar`, `foo & bar`, and `foo ^ bar` are considered "arithmetic operations". If they are, then they are not allowed to produce a trap representation result given non-trap values.

The Index of C99 and C11 standard drafts lists the bitwise operators as a subset of "arithmetic operators", suggesting yes. Though C89 doesn't organize its index that way, and my C Programming Language (2nd Edition) has a section called "arithmetic operators" which includes just `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, and `%`, leaving the bitwise operators to a separate section. In other words, there is no clear answer on this point.

In practice, I don't know of any systems where this would happen (given the constraint of non-negative values for both operands), for what that's worth.

And one may consider the following: the type `unsigned char` is expected (and essentially blessed by C99 and C11) to be capable of accessing all bits of the underlying object representation of a type - it seems likely that the intent is that bitwise operators would work correctly with `unsigned char` - which would be integer-promoted to `int` on most modern systems, an `unsigned int` on the rest: therefore it seems very unlikely that `foo | bar`, `foo & bar`, or `foo ^ bar` would be allowed to produce trap representations - at least if `foo` and `bar` are both values that can be held in an `unsigned char`, and if the result is assigned into an `unsigned char`.

It is very tempting to generalize from the prior two points that this is a non-issue, although I wouldn't call it a rigorous proof.

## Applied to the Example

Here's why I think this is correct and will work as expected:

1. `UCHAR_MAX >> 1` subjects `UCHAR_MAX` to "usual arithmetic conversions": By definition, `UCHAR_MAX` will fit into either an `int` or `unsigned int`, because on most systems `int` can represent all values of `unsigned char`, and on the few that don't, an `unsigned int` has to be able to represent all values of unsigned char`, so that's just an "integer promotion" in this case.
2. Because bit shifts are defined in terms of values and not bitwise representations, `UCHAR_MAX >> 1` is the quotient of UCHAR_MAX being divided by 2. (Let's call this result `UCHAR_MAX_DIV_2`).
3. `UCHAR_MAX_DIV_2 + 1` subjects both arguments to usual arithmetic conversion: If `UCHAR_MAX` fit into an `int`, then the result is an `int`, otherwise, it is an `unsigned int`. Either way the conversions stop at integer promotion.
4. The result of `UCHAR_MAX_DIV_2 + 1` is a positive value, which, when converted into an `unsigned char`, will have the *most significant bit* of the `unsigned char` set, and all other bits cleared (because the conversion would preserve the numerical value, and `unsigned char` is very strictly defined to have a pure binary representation without any padding bits or trap representations - but even without such an explicit requirement, the resulting value would have the most significant *value* bit set).
5. The `(unsigned char)` cast of `MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT` is actually redundant in this context - cast or no cast, it's going to be subject to the "usual arithmetic conversions" when bitwise-OR'ed. (but it might be useful in other contexts).
6. The above five steps will be constant-folded on pretty much every compiler out there - but a proper compiler should not constant-fold in a way which differs from the semantics of the code if it hadn't, so all of the above applies.
7. `val | MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT` is where it gets interesting: unlike `<<` and `>>`, `|` and the other binary operators *are* defined in terms of manipulating the binary representations. Both `val` and `MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT` are subject to usual arithmetic conversions: details like the layout of bits or trap representations might mean a different binary representation, but should preserve the *value*: Given two variables of the same integer-type, holding non-negative, non-trap values, the value bits should "line up" correctly, so I actually expect that `val | MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT` produces the correct value (let's call this result `VAL_WITH_MSB_SET`). I don't see an explicit guarantee that this step couldn't produce a trap representation, but I don't believe there's an implementation of C where it would.
8. `byte = VAL_WITH_MSB_SET` forces a conversion: conversion of an integer type (so long as the value is a non-trap value) into a smaller, unsigned integer type is well defined: In this case, the *value* is reduced modulo `UCHAR_MAX + 1`. Since `val` is stated to be *positive*, the end result is that `byte` has the *value* of the remainder of `VAL_WITH_MSB_SET` divided by `UCHAR_MAX + 1`.

## Explaining Where It Doesn't Work

If `val` were to be a negative value or non-integer type, we'd be out of luck because there is no longer a logical certainty that the bits that get binary-OR'ed will have the same "meaning":

1. If `val` is a signed integer type but has a negative value, then even though `MOST_SIGNIFICANT_BIT` is promoted to a compatible type, even though the value bits "line up", the result doesn't have any *guaranteed* meaning (because C makes no guarantee about how negative numbers are encoded), nor is the result (for any encoding) going to have the same meaning, especially once assigned into the `unsigned char` at the last step.
2. If `val` has a non-integer type, it's already violating the C standard, which constrains `|`, `&`, and `^` operators to operating on the "integer types". But if your compiler allowed it (or you did some tricks using unions, etc), then you have no guarantees about what each bit means, and thus the bit that you set are meaningless.

Comment: regarding "are these arithmetic operations", [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665835/what-is-the-definition-of-arithmetic-operation-in-c99)

Answer (score 2):

> In many ways, this question boils down to whether a conforming implementation is allowed to take two non-trap, non-negative values as operands to the bitwise operators, and produce a trap representation result

This is covered by C11 section 6.2.6.2  (C99 is similar). There is a footnote that clarifies the intent of the more technical text:

> Regardless, no arithmetic operation on valid values can generate a trap representation other than as part of an exceptional condition such as an overflow, and this cannot occur with unsigned types.

The bitwise operators are arithmetic operations [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24665835/what-is-the-definition-of-arithmetic-operation-in-c99).

In this footnote, "trap representation" excludes the special case "negative zero". The negative zero may or may not cause UB, but it has its own text (in 6.2.6.2 also) separate from the trap representation text.

So your question can actually be answered for both signed and unsigned values; the only dangerous case is the "negative zero" possibility. (Which can't occur from non-negative input).