# Initialize a 16mb array in C

Tags: arrays, c, segmentation-fault, malloc, heap-memory

I am relatively new to 'C' and would appreciate some insight on this topic.

Basically, I am trying to create a 16 MB array and check if the memory content is initialized to zero or '\0' or some garbage value for a school project.

Something like this:

`char buffer[16*1024*1024];`

I know there is a limit on the size of the program stack and obviously I get a segmentation fault. Can this somehow be done using malloc()?

Comment: Note: Many systems today use a 32-bit `int`, so `16*1024*1024` is not an issue.  Take care on some CPUs (like some embedded devices) where 16-bit `int` still occur and `16*1024*1024` overflows.  Code could use `16L*1024*1024` (added L).   Of course, using a 16 MB array is unlikely on a 16-bit `int` device.

Comment: @chux: Can you please elaborate a little about what 'L' stands for? Its general purpose usage? That would be great.

Comment: `L` makes a constant at least type `long`.  `long` integers have at least a range of about -2,000,000,000 to  +2,000,000,000 range. (-power(2,31)+1 ... power(2,31)-1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can initialize the memory with malloc like so:

```
#define MEM_SIZE_16MB   ( 16 * 1024 * 1024 )

char *buffer = malloc(MEM_SIZE_16MB * sizeof(char) );
if (buffer == NULL ) {
    // unable to allocate memory. stop here or undefined behavior happens
}
```

You can then check the values in memory so (note that this will print for a very very long time):

```
for (int i = 0; i < MEM_SIZE_16MB; i++) {
    if( i%16 == 0 ) {
        // print a newline and the memory address every 16 bytes so 
        // it's a little easier to read
        printf("\nAddr: %08p: ", &buffer[i]); 
    }
    printf("%02x ", buffer[i]);
}
printf("\n");  // one final newline
```

Don't forget to free the memory when finished

```
free(buffer);
```

Comment: Do we have to explicitly free this allocated memory? I thought when the program is done executing, the memory is automatically released back to the OS. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Yes, it is in this case but it's good practice to do in general.  For any non-trivial code, a program will usually run for a while so: 1 malloc = 1 free.  Since OP is clearly new to C, better start off on the right track right away.

Comment: `printf("\nAddr: 0x%08x: ", (unsigned int)(&buffer[i]));`



warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size. Is it more convenient to use a %p?

Comment: @Absolut_Red: yes, that's a better way.  I'll edit to reflect that.

Comment: Also the '0x' prefix doubles up. If that could be taken off

Answer (score 2):

Sure:

```
int memSize = 16*1024*1024;
char* buffer = malloc( memSize );
if ( buffer != 0 )
{
    // check contents
    for ( i = 0; i < memSize; i++ )
    {
        if ( buffer[i] != 0 )
        {
            // holler
            break;
        }
    }


    free( buffer );
}
```

Comment: Since the user is 'new' to C you should probably include the an example of free.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you will probably need to do this using `malloc()`, and here's why:

When any program *(process ... thread ...)* is started, it is given a chunk of memory which it uses to store *(among other things ...)* "local" variables.  This area is called "the **stack**."  It most-certainly won't be big enough to store 16 megabytes.

But there's *another* area of memory which any program can use:  its "**heap**."  This area *(as the name, "heap," is intended to imply ...)* has no inherent structure: it's simply a pool of storage, and it's usually big enough to store many megabytes.  You simply `malloc()` the number of bytes you need, and `free()` those bytes when you're through.

Simply define a `type` that corresponds to the structure you need to store, then `malloc(sizeof(type))`. The storage will come from the heap. (And that, basically, is what the heap is *for* ...)

Incidentally, there's a library function called `calloc()` which will reserve an area that is "known zero."  Furthermore, it might use clever operating-system tricks to do so very efficiently.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, code can not check if `buffer` is not zeroed without risking undefined behavior.  Had the type been `unsigned char`, then no problem.  But `char`, which may be signed, may have a trap value.  Attempting to work with that value leads to UB.

```
char buffer[16*1024*1024];
// Potential UB
if (buffer[0])  ...
```

Better to use `unsigned char` which cannot have trap values.

```
#define N (16LU*1204*1204)
unsigned char *buffer = malloc(N);
if (buffer) {
   for (size_t i = 0; i<N; i++) {
     if (buffer[i]) Note_NonZeroValue();
   }
}

// Clean-up when done.
free(buffer);
buffer = 0;
```

---

The tricky thing about C is that even if `char` does not have a trap value, some smart compiler could identify code is attempting something that is UB *per the spec* and then optimize `if (buffer[0])` into *nothing*.  Reading uninitialized non-`unsigned char` data is a no-no.

Comment: Your code does check if buffer is zeroed without risking UB so the first sentence needs to be edited.  Also, C11 is that it's OK to read a trap representation via a character type so I think the `char *` version was OK

Comment: @Matt McNabb scanned C11 and did not see clearly where a `char` trap was OK.  Any details appreciated.

Comment: @Matt McNabb http://stackoverflow.com/a/6725981/2410359 and https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.std.c/rRfT9fa6ga8 may be useful. in the short term.  Will need to dig deep into C11 later.

Comment: C99+TC2 (N1124) and C11 both clearly say in 6.2.6.1/5, " If the stored value of an object has such a representation **and is read by an lvalue expression that does not have character type**, the behavior is undefined."  So it doesn't matter whether `char` has trap representations or not; even if it does, reading them does not cause UB.   Although I guess you could argue that it also doesn't say what happens when a trap representation of `char` does get read, and anything not defined is undefined.

Comment: C11 adds in the clause "`signed char` shall not have any padding bits". It can still have the trap representation negative zero, so I take 6.2.6.1/5 to say that reading the negative zero does not , in itself, cause UB;  but then we refer to the rules about negative zeros in 6.2.6.2 to see whether what is subsequently done with the value triggers UB or not.

Comment: @Matt McNabb Suspect your understanding is closer to the mark than mine.  IAC, reading unitalicized data, as that is OP's issue here, is, at least, not a good programming paradigm.

Comment: No argument there, although it seems OP's been asked to do it for an assignment!   Also, sometimes I wonder if more man-hours have been spent discussing trap representations on the internet than actually coding on machines that have them....