# Why it is not safe casting a pointer to a numeric type?

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, casting

consider this code

```
T* pa = new T(13);
int address = reinterpret_cast<int>(pa);
```

Where T can be any built-in type.

1) I can not understand what's wrong with reinterpret cast here ??

2) What are the cases when this kind of casting will lead to an undefined behavour ?

3) Will `pa` always contain the correct decimal representation of a memory address ?

Comment: ints and pointers are not required to be the same size

Comment: If `1 << (sizeof(T*) * CHAR_BIT)` is greater than `INT_MAX`, then the value of your address might not fit in the `int`.

Comment: @NeilButterworth okay, lets say address is big enough to contain that hex value, lets say its long long

Comment: Typically `sizeof(int) < sizeof(T *)`, so the value of "address" will not be able to represent the value of `pa`. As long as you only print `address` for your amusement it will be fine, but as soon as you want to use it for something useful you can't.

Comment: @Cornstalks Ah yes, I got confused there for a sec. Thanks :)

Comment: Also, [`[u]intptr_t`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/integer) exists for this very purpose.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can not understand what's wrong with reinterpret cast here?

Because `int`s and pointers are not required by the standard to have the same size, thus you might lose information by casting.

> What are the cases when this kind of casting will lead to an undefined behavior?

When this is true:

```
1 << (sizeof(T*) * CHAR_BIT) > INT_MAX
```

then the value of the address might not fill in an `int`, which invokes Undefined Behavior.

> Will `pa` always contain the correct decimal representation of a memory address ?

If you use [std::[u]intptr_t](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer), then yes, since these types are guaranteed to be able to hold the value of a pointer.

Comment: minor nitpick: you are linking the C reference, not the C++ one

Comment: I actually meant [this one](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer) (since it contains information that this type is only part of the standard since C++11 and is also optional)

Comment: so the std::[u]intptr_t will always have bigger or equal size than the pointer type ?

Comment: @ampawd it will have the size need to store the value of a pointer, so basically yes...

Comment: @gsamaras there's no such reasons, thats the most informative answer

Comment: As someone that knows little about C++ types, Is there any reason to use `intptr_t` over `int64_t`?

Comment: @NickA - It depends on how portable you want to be. Some systems don't have an `int64_t` [like this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6972551/597607).

Answer (score 2):

The size of `T*` and `int` depends on your compiler and architecture.

If `sizeof(T*) > sizeof(int)` you'll discard information. While this might be true on one compiler and architecture might not be true on another.

You can use either `std::intptr_t` or `std::uintptr_t` instead of `int`. These two are guaranteed to be big enough to hold the value of a pointer.

Answer (score 1):

As other answers have pointed out, the size of an integer and the size of a pointer don't have to be the same. For example, on many 64-bit Intel machines a pointer is 64 bits and an integer is only 32.

There are other reasons to prevent this as well, though. For example, some older processor architectures have integer representations that include [*trap representations*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6725981) that result in undefined behavior if used. This means that in principle a pointer could fit into the size of an integer, but casting a pointer to an integer could result in a trap representation that causes further numeric calculations to fail.