# Precision of floating-point data types in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, floating-point, precision, long-double

Why don't the precision of floating-point data types grow proportional to its size? E.g.:

```
std::cout << sizeof(float) << "\n";  // this gives 4 on my machine "debian 64 bit" with "gcc 6.3.0"  
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits10  << "\n"; // gives 6

std::cout << sizeof(double) << "\n";  // gives 8
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10 <<  "\n"; // gives 15

std::cout << sizeof(long double) <<  "\n";  // gives 16
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits10  << "\n"; // gives 18
```

As you can see the precision of `double` is about double as precision of `float`, and that makes sense as the size of `double` is double as size of `float`.

But this is not the same case between `double` and `long double`, the size of `long double` is 128-bit which is twice as that of 64-bit `double`, but its precision is only three digits more!!

I have no idea how floating-point numbers are implemented, but from a rational standpoint does it even make sense to use 64 bits more of memory for only three digits of precision?!

I searched around but was not able to find a simple, straightforward answer.
If someone could explain why the precision of `long double` only three digits more than `double`, can you also explain why this is not the same case as between `double` and `float`?

And I also want to know how can I get better precision, without defining my own data type which obviously going to be at expense of performance?

Comment: Based on your numbers, the why isn't so much a C++ question as an [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) question.

Comment: The [Wikipedia article on this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic) is actually pretty comprehensive.  `long double` here is probably just [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format), but padded to a whole number of 64-bit words.

Comment: The largest machine-native floating point on most platforms is only 80 bits.

Comment: Some of the additional bits may be used for the exponent rather than the mantissa, which would increase the magnitude more than the precision. Try printing [`std::numeric_limits<...>::max_exponent`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_exponent) for each.

Comment: So, most of the storage for `long double` is wasted. they have to be aligned on a 16-byte boundary, but only use 10 bytes of it. :-/

Comment: use `-mlong-double-128` and the values will be closer to what you expected. @Omnifarious you can reduce the waste with `-m96bit-long-double`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Precision" is not all that is to a floating point value.  It's also about "magnitude" (not sure if that term is correct though!): How big (or small) can the represented values become?

For that, try printing also the `max_exponent` of each type:

```
std::cout << "float: " << sizeof(float) << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::digits << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<float>::max_exponent << "\n";

std::cout << "double: " << sizeof(double) << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<double>::max_exponent << "\n";

std::cout << "long double: " <<  sizeof(long double) << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits << "\n";
std::cout << std::numeric_limits<long double>::max_exponent << "\n";
```

Output on [ideone](https://ideone.com/lhfG7h):

```
float: 4
24
128
double: 8
53
1024
long double: 16
64
16384
```

So the extra bits are not all used to represent more digits (precision) but allow the exponent to be larger.  Using the wording from [IEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754) `long double` mostly increases the *exponent range* rather than the precision.

The format which is shown by my ideone sample above shows (probably) the  ["x86 extended precision format"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#x86_extended_precision_format) which assigns 1 bit for the integer part, 63 bits for the fraction part (together 64 digits) and 15 bits (2^(15-1) = 16384, 1 bit used for the sign of the exponent) for the exponent.

Note that the C++ standard only requires `long double` to be at least as precise as `double`, so `long double` could be either a synonym to `double`, the shown x86 extended precision format (most likely) or better (AFAIK only GCC on PowerPC).

> And I also want to know how can I get better precision, without defining my own data type which obviously going to be at expense of performance?

You need to either write it on your own (surely a learning experience, best not to do for production code) or use a library, like [GNU MPFR](https://www.mpfr.org/) or [Boost.Multiprecision](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/multiprecision/doc/html/).

Comment: Your results appear to confirm that `long double` on that platform is an 80-bit floating  point, as suggested in the comments on the question.

Comment: @FredLarson Indeed, 64 (digits) + 15 (exponent) + 1 (sign) = 80 :)

Comment: "not sure if that term is correct though". I assume you mean the **range** of the floating point type: how big or small can they be?

Answer (score 2):

The C++ standard does not set fixed requirements for floating-point types, aside from some minimum levels they must meet.

Likely the C++ implementation you are using targets an Intel processor. Aside from the common IEEE-754 basic 32-bit and 64-bit binary floating-point formats, Intel has an 80-bit format. Your C++ implementation is probably using that for `long double`.

Intel’s 80-bit format has 11 more bits for the significand than the 64-bit `double` format does. (It actually uses 64 where the `double` format uses 52, but one of them is reserved for an explicit leading 1.) 11 more bits means 2<sup>11</sup>=2048 times as many significand values, which is about three more decimal digits.

The 80-bit format (which is ten bytes) is preferentially aligned to multiples of 16 bytes, so six bytes of padding are included to make the `long double` size a multiple of 16 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

There many incorrect assumptions in your question

First, there's no requirement regarding types' sizes in C++. The standard only mandates a *minimum precision* of each type and that...

> ... The type `double` provides at least as much precision as `float`, and the type `long double` provides at least as much precision as `double`. The set of values of the type `float` is a subset of the set of values of the type `double`; the set of values of the type `double` is a subset of the set of values of the type `long double`. The value representation of floating-point types is implementation-defined.
>
> http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf

Most modern implementations map `float` and `double` to *IEEE-754 single and double-precision* formats though, as hardware support for them is mainstream. However `long double` don't have such wide support, because few people need higher precision than double, and hardware for those cost a lot more. Therefore some platforms map it to IEEE-754 double-precision, i.e. the same as `double`. Some others map it to the [80-bit IEEE 754 extended-precision format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_precision#IEEE_754_extended_precision_formats) if the underlying hardware supports it. Otherwise `long double` will be represented by [`double-double` arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format#Double-double_arithmetic) or [IEEE-754 quadruple-precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadruple-precision_floating-point_format)

Moreover precision also **doesn't scale linearly to the number of bits in the type**. It's easy to see that `double` is ***more than twice*** as precise as `float` and ***8 times wider range*** than `float` despite only twice the storage, because it has 53 bits of significand compared to 24 in float and 3 more exponent bits. Types can also have [trap representations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6725809/995714) or padding bits so different types may have different ranges even though they have the same size and belong to the same category (integral or floating-point)

So the important thing here is [`std::numeric_limits<long double>::digits`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/digits). If you print that you'll see that `long double` has 64 bits of significand which is just 11 bits more than `double`. [See it live](https://tio.run/##pY/RCoIwFIbvfYqD3SgUVJfLfBIhbE45MLdwZzdFz76ckkpYhJ6rcc7/f@Pjt9uu4txtUHFpCwEJakONyOs0GHcSaySTOlQEdY4qioNHAO0YKhjj2hIkCYSl1DmxjDIyeBdwhtCv/VuXUXeMu5Yfn99CgVULPuyHrOcpW4sG@aX/NemKKWPv7Czi@D@h62UqPM0YFNpepfim0F@XOPTNVRIfiF8WUqsKBpUZkUlgic2kvkppjjN6PZ17AQ). That means your compiler uses the 80-bit extended-precision for `long double`, the rest is just **padding bytes** to keep the alignment. In fact [gcc has various options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/x86-Options.html) that will change your output:

- `-malign-double` and `-mno-align-double` for controlling the alignment of `long double`
- `-m96bit-long-double` and `-m128bit-long-double` for changing the padding size
- `-mlong-double-64`, `-mlong-double-80` and `-mlong-double-128` for controlling the underlying `long double` implementation

By changing the options you'll get the below results for `long double`

- [`-mlong-double-128`](https://tio.run/##pY/LCsIwEEX3/YqhbixYsK4k1n5JQWKaloE8xKQbxV83NilWkSrSzirM3HvCYadT2jDmFqiYaCsOOWpjz5zKInrtBEq0pnCoLEiKaplE1wi6MbYihOnWQp5DXAtNLSltaQ1eOOwh9mv/1vUyHJPQ8uPzK6iw6cDZesh6nmolPyM79L/moVgQ8syOIjb/E0KvVPFuxKDS7VHwbwr9dYpD35wl8YH4ZSG0amBQGRF5C0yxeavPUhrjvLxuzt1ZLWhjXCp9NO2jabbZPgA): size = 16, digits10 = 33, digits2 = 113
- [`-m96bit-long-double`](https://tio.run/##pY/bCoJAEIbvfYrBbgwSqougzXwSIXRdZWAP4o43Ra/e5iodCIuouVpm/u9fPt40cc25m6HmsisFJGgstSJXafDYSVRINnWoCVSOOpoHpwD6sVQyxk1HkCQQVtLkxDLKyOJRwB5Cv/ZvU0XDcT5Qfnx@ASXWffFqec/6Pt0p0SI/jL8mA5gydstOVqy/bxi4TIe7CYPSdIUU7xTG6y8OI/mXxEvFJwtpdA13lQmRp8AvNk/4X0pTPQ@vs3MXXsm8ti5W202BFHsgHoEr): size = 12, digits10 = 18, digits2 = 64
- [`-mlong-double-64`](https://tio.run/##pY/dCoJAEEbvfYrBbhQSKqKLzXwSIWxdZWB/xF1vil69zVVSCYuwuVpmvu8sh1ZVVFJqVygpb3IGMSptapaJxBt3HAUanViUBkSGMgi9mwftaJMTQlVjII7BL7jKDElNajReGZzAd2v3VkXQHcOu5cbl15Bj2YK3myHreLIRrEZ67n@Nu2JCyCs7i9j9Tuh6qfSPMwa5ai6cfVLor0sc@uZfEm@IbxZcyRIGlRmRSWCJzaT@l9IcZ/S6W/ugBc9KbSPholEfjQ77Jw): size = 8, digits10 = 15, digits2 = 53

You'll get size = 10 if you disable padding, but that'll come at a performance expense due to misalignment. See more demo on [compiler explorer](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAM1QDsCBlZAQwBtMQBGAFlICsupVs1qhkAUgBMAISnTSAZ0ztkBPHUqZa6AMKpWAVwC2tQVvQAZPLUwA5YwCNMxLgDZSAB1QLC62nsMTQS8fNTorG3sjJxdOdyUVMNoGAmZiAgDjU05FZUxVPxS0ggi7R2c3RVT0zKCchWqS6zLoiriASkVUA2JkDgByKQBma2RDLABqcSGddQbiTGYjaexxAAYAQWHR8cwpmdY8I0IFFfWtzesCCaNmawh28/EAdllNiY%2BJhvQQFG7r6Y6QFTSSSKisVDMAggcQAVh0BDhCJ8AC89tMACIgyT7IEzL54NGoKjUCFQx7vT5UwHAqSSUgTfDAE6cNb7LF03HA76/WjGZx4ZAAfUOxwIpxm4MhiKG2F%2BTJZa3OVOpM1poIZCvFOMx2K5%2BJ5ID5RgFwtFJ0BUqhK3leGZ4v1OmxSNodOmbw2VMNaAMALV%2BLp6G6DnYMPhiPDqPRQw5oMdBKJJKDBhDmApnpVHxpAY1jLtivZeuzTsNxtNIqOFpmydTNpAWoUrOVmfjdM1%2Be1hc5xa%2BBB%2BRv5xEFFbFEp0NfYdYbrdBLrdQw9Xr7vx9frxTrpENEjODoaR4sJ0djOv9JcPxIgW%2BAO5T7HTLZn9Lz9sbbN13dPvf7ZaHZsr4sBK8b1rWVbRfJtKUzHs22fE4T2PeNS0HYdzQAg46GvCdMCnDsFEfOdZwXJ5ngxc5%2Bk6VgQH6WF%2BlIUx%2BjWWjUCooEZDkL5ul6dFJCGThaOhBjyM6ABrEAeIAOlcbhuFcZ5XFcAAOTgAE41meSRYSEKjuFo%2BjGNIZj%2BlohQQDWUgBMYzo4FgGBED%2BIwPDwdgyAoCA0AcpyKmAZT6SoJyCGcEyIAcKj9Icaw0gATyovjSHck16AAeVoVhosE0gsFuURQ3S/AFgKAA3TATPSzAAA98l9AZ9KuZRQtow4HGIKK9CwGL%2BKHIx2s6Gh6CYNgOB4fhBGEUQUDkOQhDwBwTMgTpUA8JISoAWkSnFlqMK9lqw5bOEkBTjLyAoNAgcxamyUhzFKKIYmCbxfDoc67tCPxrvKWJckSQpGie%2BojqSIp0je1oPoaYpfqqYpgduzhOgUTi%2Bi4CiqJouj6oMqiyoU1xlqkiZgGQZAJmU8ScQgXBCBIEFeIZPQPOc6nYYmVjZBkfj6qspB3Mc5zyEobnPJcbzfP8wLKBC9LwtoKL2ri1AjASghktS9HMpEYAcv0vL8jUIqSv08rKoC9Haso9LGua4hItagZYoITrutIXrGBYUMhoEelRrECaZCmmb4Hmxa/BWtaJg25TXHCghlq2rDDq%2Bk6zv0LIzG0aG2k8e6kghkIHtodPQf%2B77weTupPp14ugeaG6M7BmpS4uuumkid6ka6HpEdhrTqN09HDKxnG8YJomSbJimiGIRnaflnnnGpyR2mZn3pHZwTOfs2eXP5mfBZAYWndF4ggolsKIqt2X4q0JWUrSrXMCyjXqto7XCuK9HDeQKqTfoOrzemy3rYYFth1I4jtnb9TdrwAQQwhDq3GmxX2jVZoPAMkHOgId1qbQwttXcmBcY6XLsdUwp1tAQyutXVuORc7Zwbs9POBdBAJArnQQGGRaF/QTskRoDD6g/XYZDKuLcQZt3hh3QayMe5o3Sv3bG%2BD8aE2JqTCY5N8ATynszHeDNhhDEXizOQq9LIiRAK4NY4k9rcFZJwBSykLHYyUt3AhXVYRmT0kxKixkxLmQ5qQaydl/geF9HzNymiM6YFUSQQQ4DXaDV4AAd2ah4R2ZtUauIxoMHinAJixMIAgCYA85HD0UZIAx5EfFIH8YE1yAtnKeLCZTD6USBpcDiQkpJKNe7SKosMHE2SCC5PyUPBRo8SnrwqQQIJ1SKgwLqRPSJdAXZNKGvE5giT%2Bh8QkSkvuXSeJDCyTkvJsjBkj1JiMzoCBFhYBcCgs2jiQDOKkfpQyHizIWSEqQUSclxJDFhLCIYOyrFrB8s8XgZshgdMee4rxa8JHFIeW4oyULDGkCKkfPwIBuBAA)

In PowerPC you can also [see the same phenomena when changing the floating-point format](https://godbolt.org/#g:!((g:!((g:!((h:codeEditor,i:(j:1,lang:c%2B%2B,source:%27%23include+%3Climits%3E%0A%0Aint+get(int+%26size,+int%26+digits2)%0A%7B%0A++++size+%3D+sizeof(long+double)%3B%0A++++digits2+%3D+std::numeric_limits%3Clong+double%3E::digits%3B%0A++++return+std::numeric_limits%3Clong+double%3E::digits10%3B%0A%7D%0A%27),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27C%2B%2B+source+%231%27,t:%270%27)),k:34.81384715871979,l:%274%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27),(g:!((h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppc64g8,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27power64+AT12.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%231)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27),(h:compiler,i:(compiler:ppc64g8,filters:(b:%270%27,binary:%271%27,commentOnly:%270%27,demangle:%270%27,directives:%270%27,execute:%271%27,intel:%270%27,libraryCode:%271%27,trim:%271%27),lang:c%2B%2B,libs:!(),options:%27-O2+-mabi%3Dieeelongdouble%27,source:1),l:%275%27,n:%270%27,o:%27power64+AT12.0+(Editor+%231,+Compiler+%233)+C%2B%2B%27,t:%270%27)),k:65.1861528412802,l:%274%27,m:100,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,s:0,t:%270%27)),l:%272%27,n:%270%27,o:%27%27,t:%270%27)),version:4). With `-mabi=ibmlongdouble` (double-double arithmetic, which is the default) you'll get (size, digits10, digits2) = (16, 31, 106) but with `-mabi=ieeelongdouble` the tuple will become (16, 33, 113)

For more information you should read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_double

> And I also want to know how can I get better precision, without defining my own data type

The keyword to search is [arbitrary-precision arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbitrary-precision_arithmetic). There are various libraries for that which you can find in the [List of arbitrary-precision arithmetic software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_arbitrary-precision_arithmetic_software). You can find more information in the tags [bigint](/questions/tagged/bigint), [biginteger](/questions/tagged/biginteger) or [arbitrary-precision](/questions/tagged/arbitrary-precision)