# Anomaly when adding floating points of high precision

Tags: c++, floating-point, addition, precision

Consider the following example:

```
int main()
{
    float x = 1.0f;
    float a = 0.0000000000000001f; //16 floating point
    
    std::cout<<std::fixed;
    
    std::cout<< std::setprecision(16) <<  a + a <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< std::setprecision(16) <<  x + a + a <<std::endl;
}
```

The result of the prints are:

```
0.0000000000000002 // OK
1.0000000000000000 // NOK ???
```

Online code: https://rextester.com/ITHF23448

Question: Why is the 2 being elided from the result of the second addition? The correct answer should have been 1.00000000000000**2**

Btw, this example produces the same results in Python, so I have a feeling it's not language related.

Comment: Try `std::setprecision(256)`, which should show enough digits to see the wiggly bits.

Comment: `float` does not have 16 digits of accuracy.

Comment: Typical precision of a `float` is (about) 6 decimal digits.   For IEEE floating point (which a lot of implementations support, but is not mandatory in C++) a related link is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55767385/precision-of-floating-point-data-types-in-c

Comment: If you want higher precision in your floating point, use `double`.

Comment: @Eljay This is not an issue with the "wiggly" bits. The 2 at the end is intentional as it is a variable definition.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews This is not language related. I used C++ for the example, but you can see the same output in Python. Also, a double won't resolve the issue.

Comment: A `float` only has a limited number of digits of precision.  Your `x + a + a` exceeds the number of digits of precision, so the value is rounded or truncated.  Here's an example of how to check how many digits of precision you have available to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50970282/4641116

Comment: And by *wiggly bits*, I meant that `a + a` is equal to `0.0000000000000002000000033724767052774329290087962363031692802906036376953125`.  The tail part varies from what you might expect because the value provided cannot be represented exactly, so it is approximated to the nearest representable value.

Comment: @Eljay: Thank you for the SO link. My question is not about `a+a`, but `x+a+a`. As you can see from my example `a+a` returns the correct result, but `x+a+a` does not, no matter how many digits you extend the output with. The question is why does this occur when you add `x+a+a`?

Comment: Accuracy has already been lost internally, so asking for more digits in the output does not make sense; see the answers to the questions listed at the top. With `x+a+a`, you have an absorption because `a` is much smaller than `x`, which is not the case for `a+a`.

Comment: A `float` has only so many digits of precision.  `1.000000000000002` exceeds the digits of precision, so the value is rounded to `1.000000000000000`.