# Why does C allow the sizeof operator on a variable that hasn't yet been created?

Tags: c, sizeof

Consider the following example code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) {
    int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
    *a = 5;
    free(a);
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, I allocate the integer `a` on the heap and initialize it to 5. This line specifically

```
int *a = malloc(sizeof *a);
```

is what is confusing me (the `sizeof *a` part). To me, this looks like I am trying to get the size of the variable before it is even created, but I see this style for initializing pointers is extremely common. When I compile this code with clang, I don't get any errors or warnings. Why does the compiler allow this? As far as I can tell, this is akin to doing something like

```
int a = a + 1;
```

without any previous declaration of `a`. This produces a warning with `clang -Wall main.c`:

```
main.c:17:13: warning: variable 'a' is uninitialized when used
      within its own initialization [-Wuninitialized]
    int a = a + 1;
```

What makes this line different from the pointer declaration with `sizeof`?

Comment: Why wouldn't it? If you know it's type, you know its size. Why should it matter whether it's been allocated?

Comment: Also: it is `sizeof expr` and expr can even be a constant, try `sizeof '@'`, for instance ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For most cases `sizeof` is a *compile-time* operator. The compiler simply knows the size of the type you pass to it.

Secondly, actually at the time `malloc` is called the variable `a` actually have been defined. The variable must have been defined (and allocated) before it can be initialized. Otherwise, where would the initialization value be written?

---

The problem with

```
int a = a + 1;
```

isn't that `a` doesn't exist, it's that the value of `a` is *indeterminate* when you use it in `a + 1`.

For some types an indeterminate value could contain a [*trap representation*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation), and if that happens it leads to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

---

A small note about the `sizeof` operator: The only time it's *not* evaluated by the compiler itself at compile-time is for [variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array).

Answer (score 4):

The operand of the `sizeof` operator is **not** evaluated unless it is a variable length array.  It is only looked at to determine its type.

This behavior is documented in section 6.5.3.4p2 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The `sizeof` operator  yields  the  size  (in  bytes)  of  its  operand,  which  may  be  an expression or the parenthesized name of a type.  The size is determined from the type of the operand.  The result is an integer.  **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type, the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and the result is an integer constant.**

In this case, it knows that `*a` has type `int`, so `*a` is not evaluated and `sizeof *a` is the same as `sizeof(int)`.