# Is it safe to read the value of numpy.empty or jax.numpy.empty?

Tags: c, numpy, memory, language-lawyer, jax

In Flax, we typically initialize a model by passing in a random vector and let the library figure the correct shape for the parameters via shape inference. For example, this is what [the tutorial](https://flax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/notebooks/annotated_mnist.html#create-train-state) did

```py
def create_train_state(rng, learning_rate, momentum):
  """Creates initial `TrainState`."""
  cnn = CNN()
  params = cnn.init(rng, jnp.ones([1, 28, 28, 1]))['params']
  tx = optax.sgd(learning_rate, momentum)
  return train_state.TrainState.create(
      apply_fn=cnn.apply, params=params, tx=tx)
```

It is worth noting that the concrete value of `jnp.ones([1, 28, 28, 1])` does not matter, as shape inference only relies on its shape. I can replace it with `jnp.zeros([1, 28, 28, 1])` or `jnp.random(jax.random.PRNGKey(42), [1, 28, 28, 1])`, and it will give me the exactly same result.

My question is, can I use `jnp.empty([1, 28, 28, 1])` instead? I want to use `jnp.empty` to clarify that we don't care about the value (and it could also be faster but the speedup is negligible). However, there is something called [trap representation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6725809/trap-representation) in C, and it looks like reading from `jnp.empty` without overwriting it first could trigger undefined behavior. Since Numpy is a light wrapper around C, should I worry about that?

**Bonus question**: let's forget about Jax and focus on vanilla Numpy. It is safe to read from `np.empty([...])`? Again, I don't care about the value, but I do care about not getting a segfault.

Comment: The documentation says it contains "arbitrary (uninitialized()" data. I think that means it's valid, but the values are unpredictable.

Comment: With the numeric dtype those are just bytes, and none of the `numpy` code is messed up by "reading" them.  A clever programmer might be able to handle them as code or something else, but `np.empty` doesn't give us control over that memory location. But `np.empty(..., dtype=object)` sets them all to `None`, a safe reference.  Similarly string dtypes are "blank".

Comment: *"... as shape inference only relies on its shape. I can replace it with `jnp.zeros([1, 28, 28, 1])` or `jnp.random(jax.random.PRNGKey(42), [1, 28, 28, 1])`, and it will give me the exactly same result."*  In that case, does the code actually attempt to read values from the array?  The shape is part of the metadata; there is no need to access values of the array when getting the shape.

Comment: A `segfault` is not possible, AFAIK. But it is possible to have `nan` values in `np.empty`: `b = np.array([9221120237041090560, 10, 20 ,30]); del b; a = np.empty(4); a`, then *a* should contain `np.nan` as the first value on linux.

Comment: [`jnp.empty`](https://jax.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_autosummary/jax.numpy.empty.html) fills with zeros. `np.empty` can contain trap representations `b = np.arange(65536).astype(np.uint16); del b; a = np.empty(65536, np.float16); print(a + 1.)` results in the warning "RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in add" on linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because XLA does not provide a mechanism to create uninitialized memory, in JAX `jnp.empty` is currently (v0.3.14) equivalent to `jnp.zeros` (see https://github.com/google/jax/blob/jax-v0.3.14/jax/_src/numpy/lax_numpy.py#L2007-L2009)

So at least in the current release, it is safe to refer to the contents of `jnp.empty` arrays. But if you're going to rely on that property, I'd suggest using `jnp.zeros` instead, so that if the `jnp.empty` implementation changes in the future your assumptions will still be valid.

`np.empty` is different: it will include uninitialized values, and so your program's behavior may change unpredictably from run to run if you rely on those values. There's no danger of memory corruption/segfaults when accessing these uninitialized values: the memory is allocated, it's just that the contents are uninitialized and so the values will reflect whatever bits happened to be stored there at the time the block was allocated.