# Reliable type-punning across C and C++ standards

Tags: c++, c, type-conversion, language-lawyer, type-punning

Is there a way to type-pun that is valid in both C and C++? Preferably low overhead, and avoiding trivial preprocessor hacks.

In C89, I know I can do something like this:

```
unsigned int float_bits(float num) {
    return *(unsigned int *)&num;
}
```

However this violates C99's strict aliasing rule. So something like this might be more portable across the various C standards:

```
unsigned int float_bits(float num) {
    union { float f; unsigned int i; } u;
    u.f = num;
    return u.i;
}
```

But I know that this is not valid C++, because only one member of a union can be “active” at a time. The typical solution given for both C and C++ is something like this:

```
unsigned int float_bits(float num) {
    unsigned int i;
    memcpy(&i, &num, sizeof(int));
    return i;
}
```

However, this relies on the compiler being able to optimize away the call to memcpy. Is memcpy the only method that is portable across C and C++ standards?

Comment: Hmmm, even the first `(unsigned int *)&num` is not reliable.

Comment: `memcpy` is the way to go here. Or just don't do type punning, it's rarely needed :)

Comment: Now if you post an answer that says `memcpy` is the only way, we can use this question as the canonical duplicate for all future questions of this type.

Comment: @DeiDei Why is `memcpy` any more (or less) reliable than using `(unsigned int *)&num`? (Both will fail if `sizeof(float) != sizeof(int)`.)

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica re C++ only: even if `sizeof(float) == sizeof(int)` then `*(unsigned int *)&num;` is UB. `memcpy` is valid in this case and a `static_assert` can be used to check the sizes match.

Comment: @Adrian-ReinstateMonica: `* (unsigned int *) &num` would violate C’s rule about aliasing: The compiler is entitled to assume that an access via an `unsigned int *` does not access an object that was defined as `float`, regardless of the casts. When it optimizes, code such as `num = 4; * (unsigned int *) &num = 0; printf("%d\n", num); printf("%d\n", num);` could print “4” and “0”, or “4” and “4”, or “0” and “0”, among other things.

Comment: @RichardCritten I believe I've found a non-memcpy solution involving C-style casts to unsigned char *, which is an exception to the strict aliasing rule. If we would like to make this the canonical duplicate for all future questions, perhaps I could make a community-wiki answer with all of the known "alternatives" to type-punning, and their corresponding pros/cons?

Comment: @RyanAvella: You can read through your `unsigned char*`, but how do you get any other type of value out of it?  It sounds like you’ll just end up implementing `memcpy` yourself.

Comment: @RyanAvella be aware that casting *to* a character type is allowed to access the bytes of some other type, but not the other way around.  You can't get around the casting with an intermediate cast to `char *`

Comment: The first code is also wrong in C89 (which does have the strict aliasing rule)

Comment: @curiousguy "effective type" is only relevant for malloc'd space which is not the case of this question. The effective type of a variable declared as `T` is always `T` regardless of memcpying

Comment: @M.M: There has, so far as I can tell, never been a consensus as to exactly when objects can take an effective type different from their declared type.  In this particular case, they wouldn't, but if a function is passed the address of an object of static or automatic duration, it would have no way of knowing the declared type of that object even though it should have one.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
unsigned int float_bits(float num) {
  unsigned int i;
  memcpy(&i, &num, sizeof(int));
  return i;
}
```

there is no side effect from that call of `memcpy` other than changing `i` to have the same bytes as `num` did.

It is true that compilers are free to insert a call to a library `memcpy` function here.  They are also free to insert 1 million NOOPs, a pong simulation AI training session, and try to seach the proof space for the goldblach's conjecture proof.

At some point you have to presume your compiler isn't hostile.

Every decent compiler understands what memcpy does.

Comment: in C: Does that change an effective type?

Comment: @curiousguy No.