# Are the functions memcpy, memmove and memset outdated considering the alternatives in c++?

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

In [this post](http://maintainablecode.logdown.com/posts/159916-memcpy-memmove-and-memset-are-deprecated) the author explains why the functions `memcpy`, `memmove`, and `memset` are obsolete. He claims that the alternative standard algorithms like for example `std::fill` should be used instead of the function `memset`. The author presents three reasons for his claim:

> Reason #1: The standard algorithms are type-safe
>
> Reason #2: The standard algorithms are more general
>
> Reason #3: The standard algorithms are equally efficient

Is the author right? I want to produce modern maintainable C++ code. Should I avoid using `memcpy`, `memmove` and `memset`?

Comment: It depends on the implementation. You can implement the standard library algorithms to be as efficient (essentially but using the C functions when appropriate) but you don't have to. It's probably true for most implementations but it's not necessarily true all the time. Personally, I use the algorithms until I detect that there's a problem.

Comment: It should be *very* easy to check the efficiency claim. Just check the generated assembly and write some benchmark programs (remember to build them with optimizations *enabled*).

Comment: Personally I'd go for "the standard C++ library algorithms/functions are more readable" (and often safer) and that is a big reason for using them.

Comment: Yes the author is right.

Comment: Yes the author is right.  Use `copy`, `fill`, and `move`.  The standard library implementer's are smart and for trivial types they code will use those primitives so you get the speed without having to worry about if they types change if the code will be correct or not.  Do note that the standard caveat still applies that once you are done, measure (profile/benchmark) and confirm the performance is acceptable.

Comment: Well, there's the whole issue of [type punning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58674606/reliable-type-punning-across-c-and-c-standards)

Comment: Algorithms are more readable and are _good enough_, so use them by default. But `memcpy` and company still have a place for optimization, once you've hit a bottleneck. I've run into several cases where algorithms are _just a bit_ too abstract that the compiler can't inline, optimize or vectorize them (particularly MSVC). Using the C functions is enough of a hint to the compiler to say "hey, do a really fast dumb transfer/compare".