# How to create a byte out of 8 bool values (and vice versa)?

Tags: c++, boolean, bit-manipulation, bit-packing

I have 8 `bool` variables, and I want to "merge" them into a byte.

Is there an easy/preferred method to do this?

How about the other way around, decoding a byte into 8 separate boolean values?

I come in assuming it's not an unreasonable question, but since I couldn't find relevant documentation via Google, it's probably another one of those "nonono all your intuition is wrong" cases.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean exactly. A bool(ean) datatype in c++ is one byte, how do you want to convert a byte into byte ?

Comment: There is no way to pack 8 bool variables into one byte. There is a way packing 8 logical true/false states in a single byte using Bitmasking. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth That should be an answer.

Comment: @weltraumpirat I was not sure what exactly the question was.

Comment: I just knew people were going to make this question harder than it is. Well, it's my fault for not knowing booleans are more than 1 bit in size.

Comment: Related: [How to efficiently convert an 8-bit bitmap to array of 0/1 integers with x86 SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52098873) is nice for 16 bytes at once.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The hard way:

```
unsigned char ToByte(bool b[8])
{
    unsigned char c = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < 8; ++i)
        if (b[i])
            c |= 1 << i;
    return c;
}
```

And:

```
void FromByte(unsigned char c, bool b[8])
{
    for (int i=0; i < 8; ++i)
        b[i] = (c & (1<<i)) != 0;
}
```

Or the cool way:

```
struct Bits
{
    unsigned b0:1, b1:1, b2:1, b3:1, b4:1, b5:1, b6:1, b7:1;
};
union CBits
{
    Bits bits;
    unsigned char byte;
};
```

Then you can assign to one member of the union and read from another. But note that the order of the bits in `Bits` is implementation defined.

Note that reading one union member after writing another is well-defined in ISO C99, and as an extension in several major C++ implementations (including MSVC and GNU-compatible C++ compilers), but is Undefined Behaviour in ISO C++.  `memcpy` or [C++20 `std::bit_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) are the safe ways to type-pun in portable C++.

(Also, the bit-order of bitfields within a `char` is [implementation defined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1490092/c-c-force-bit-field-order-and-alignment), as is possible padding between bitfield members.)

Comment: Can you loop on the `Bits` though?

Comment: @Juicy Not with the union directly, if you need to loop you use `<<`. But you can mix both solitions.

Comment: The Bits struct can use `unsigned char` (not unsigned) to better match the CBits union.

Comment: @sp2denny I believe no because this is `unsigned char` which means there's no trap representation.

Comment: @ibug I think type-punning through the union is undefined behavior in C++, regehr seems to say so here: https://blog.regehr.org/archives/959 I don't think the question of trap-representations is relevant. It's about the strict aliasing rule. The "cool" way shown above would be against coding standards at my company at least.

Comment: @iBug it's UB to access a member of a union that wasn't last assigned to.

Comment: Type punning through unions is UB; please remove that or explicitly state that this is an extension and which compilers provide it.

Comment: This is definitively UB.

Comment: @UKMonkey How did this question get some attention again? It's been half a year since my comment!

Comment: @ibug - it was marked as the duplicate for another question- so naturally everyone jumped to take a look see what they thought of it

Comment: doesnt FromByte create the bit array in reverse order?

Comment: @BaummitAugen Though in plain C it's not. I am aware that the question is tagged C++ but still worth noting.

Answer (score 17):

### The cool way (using the [multiplication technique](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14547087/995714))

```
inline uint8_t pack8bools(bool* a)
{
    uint64_t t;
    memcpy(&t, a, sizeof t);         //  strict-aliasing & alignment safe load
    return 0x8040201008040201ULL*t >> 56;
       // bit order: a[0]<<7 | a[1]<<6 | ... | a[7]<<0  on little-endian
       // for a[0] => LSB, use 0x0102040810204080ULL    on little-endian
}

void unpack8bools(uint8_t b, bool* a)
{
       // on little-endian,  a[0] = (b>>7) & 1  like printing order
    auto MAGIC = 0x8040201008040201ULL;  // for opposite order, byte-reverse this
    auto MASK  = 0x8080808080808080ULL;
    uint64_t t = ((MAGIC*b) & MASK) >> 7;
    memcpy(a, &t, sizeof t);    // store 8 bytes without UB
}
```

Assuming `sizeof(bool) == 1`

To portably do LSB <-> `a[0]` (like the `pext/pdep` version below) instead of using the opposite of host endianness, use `htole64(0x0102040810204080ULL)` as the magic multiplier in both versions.  ([`htole64` is from BSD / GNU  <endian.h>](https://linux.die.net/man/3/le64toh)).  That arranges the multiplier bytes to match little-endian order for the bool array.  `htobe64` with the same constant gives the other order, MSB-first like you'd use for printing a number in base 2.

You may want to make sure that the bool array is 8-byte aligned (`alignas(8)`) for performance, and that the compiler knows this.  `memcpy` is always safe for any alignment, but on ISAs that require alignment, a compiler can only inline `memcpy` as a single load or store instruction if it knows the pointer is sufficiently aligned.  `*(uint64_t*)a` would promise alignment, but also violate the strict-aliasing rule.  Even on ISAs that allow unaligned loads, they can be faster when naturally aligned. But the compiler can still inline memcpy without seeing that guarantee at compile time.

---

### How they work

Suppose we have 8 bools `b[0]` to `b[7]` whose least significant bits are named a-h respectively that we want to pack into a single byte. Treating those 8 consecutive `bool`s as one 64-bit word and load them we'll get the bits in reversed order in a little-endian machine. Now we'll do a multiplication (here dots are zero bits)

```
  |  b7  ||  b6  ||  b4  ||  b4  ||  b3  ||  b2  ||  b1  ||  b0  |
  .......h.......g.......f.......e.......d.......c.......b.......a
× 1000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  ↑......h.↑.....g..↑....f...↑...e....↑..d.....↑.c......↑b.......a
  ↑.....g..↑....f...↑...e....↑..d.....↑.c......↑b.......a
  ↑....f...↑...e....↑..d.....↑.c......↑b.......a
+ ↑...e....↑..d.....↑.c......↑b.......a
  ↑..d.....↑.c......↑b.......a
  ↑.c......↑b.......a
  ↑b.......a
  a       
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
= abcdefghxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

The arrows are added so it's easier to see the position of the set bits in the magic number. At this point 8 least significant bits has been put in the top byte, we'll just need to mask the remaining bits out

So the magic number for packing would be `0b1000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001` or `0x8040201008040201`. If you're on a big endian machine you'll need to use the magic number `0x0102040810204080` which is calculated in a similar manner

For unpacking we can do a similar multiplication

```
  |  b7  ||  b6  ||  b4  ||  b4  ||  b3  ||  b2  ||  b1  ||  b0  |
                                                          abcdefgh
× 1000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001000000001
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
= h0abcdefgh0abcdefgh0abcdefgh0abcdefgh0abcdefgh0abcdefgh0abcdefgh
& 1000000010000000100000001000000010000000100000001000000010000000
  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
= h0000000g0000000f0000000e0000000d0000000c0000000b0000000a0000000
```

After multiplying we have the needed bits at the most significant positions, so we need to mask out irrelevant bits and shift the remaining ones to the least significant positions. The output will be the bytes contain a to h in little endian.

---

### The efficient way

On newer x86 CPUs with [BMI2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI2) there are [PEXT](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html) and [PDEP](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/PDEP.html) instructions for this purpose. The `pack8bools` function above can be replaced with

```
_pext_u64(*((uint64_t*)a), 0x0101010101010101ULL);
```

And the `unpack8bools` function can be implemented as

```
_pdep_u64(b, 0x0101010101010101ULL);
```

(This maps LSB -> LSB, like a `0x0102040810204080ULL` multiplier constant, opposite of `0x8040201008040201ULL`.  x86 is little-endian: `a[0] = (b>>0) & 1;` after memcpy.)

Unfortunately [those instructions are very slow on AMD before Zen 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36951611/995714) so you may need to compare with the multiplication method above to see which is better

#### The other fast way is SSE2

x86 SIMD has an operation that takes the high bit of every byte (or float or double) in a vector register, and gives it to you as an integer.  The instruction for bytes is [`pmovmskb`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/pmovmskb).  This can of course do 16 bytes at a time with the same number of instructions, so it gets better than the multiply trick if you have lots of this to do.

```
#include <immintrin.h>

inline uint8_t pack8bools_SSE2(const bool* a)
{
    __m128i v = _mm_loadl_epi64( (const __m128i*)a );  // 8-byte load, despite the pointer type.
    // __m128 v = _mm_cvtsi64_si128( uint64 );  // alternative if you already have an 8-byte integer
    v = _mm_slli_epi32(v, 7);   // low bit of each byte becomes the highest
    return _mm_movemask_epi8(v);
}
```

There isn't a single instruction to unpack until AVX-512, which has mask-to-vector instructions.  It is doable with SIMD, but likely not as efficiently as the multiply trick.  See  [Convert 16 bits mask to 16 bytes mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67201469/convert-16-bits-mask-to-16-bytes-mask) and more generally [is there an inverse instruction to the movemask instruction in intel avx2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36488675/is-there-an-inverse-instruction-to-the-movemask-instruction-in-intel-avx2) for unpacking bitmaps to other element sizes.

[How to efficiently convert an 8-bit bitmap to array of 0/1 integers with x86 SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52098873/how-to-efficiently-convert-an-8-bit-bitmap-to-array-of-0-1-integers-with-x86-sim) has some answers specifically for 8-bits -> 8-bytes, but if you can't do 16 bits at a time for that direction, the multiply trick is probably better, and `pext` certainly is (except on CPUs where it's disastrously slow, like AMD before Zen 3).

Comment: I upvoted this because it's cute and well-illustrated, but most people who come across this question would be better off with a `std::bitset`. They probably even get the optimization for free if they use the `unsigned long long` constructor.

Comment: @BaryonsforBreakfast no, you won't get the optimization for free because each bit in the bitset is still stored as one bit and not an 8-bit byte. You do have the ability to get each bit and do operations on it though, but not in parallel so it'll be slower. The 8 bytes -> 8 bits direction also doesn't work automatically with bitset

Comment: Sorry, I meant that the packing and unpacking CPU instructions under "the efficient way" are probably free when they're available if you use the `unsigned long long` constructor (and `to_ullong` to unpack). Going between the array of `bool`s and the `unsigned long long`s would still not be free in that you'd still have to do the casts by hand.

Comment: `to_ullong` and the `unsigned long long` constructor can't use PEXT and PDEP because they just copy the `unsigned long long` value directly to/from the internal array. The bits in bitset are stored as bits in the array and not one bit per byte. So `to_ullong` gives you 64 bits and not 8

Comment: Has anyone run into incorrect answers with `gcc` 8 and 9 when `-O2` is enabled? I get wrong answers after a packing and unpacking when `-O2` is used, while it gives correct answers without optimization. Note, using `clang`, it gives correct answers even when `-O2` is on.

Comment: Add another comment to address my previous comment regarding incorrect answers with `gcc` when `-O2` is turned on: I found that using `std::memcpy()` instead of type punning would resolve the incorrect answer issue.

Comment: @SamuelLi that's probably due to [strict aliasing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/98650/995714). Try `-fno-strict-aliasing` or a union. Or just change from `bool` to `char` because `char*` can alias other types

Comment: @phuclv using `char` instead of `bool` would give me correct answers. But gcc still complains `dereferencing type-punned pointer will break strict-aliasing rules`. This is interesting behavior of gcc though.

Comment: @SamuelLi: That's because using `uint64_t*` to read a `char[]` object violates strict-aliasing.  ISO C only allows it the other way around: using `char *` to read an object that was originally a `uint64_t`.  If the only access to the char object is through a `char*`, you're fine, but if there's any use of an automatic or static storage `char[]`, you have UB.  This answer should really use `memcpy` or C++20 `std::bitcast`, or GNU C `typedef uint64_t unaligned_aliasing_u64 __attribute__((aligned(1), may_alias));` to do the type-punning; pointer-casting is never safe.

Comment: @PeterCordes Thanks for your explanation, but I don't quite get what you said about automatic or static storage. Could you elaborate what it means to be automatic or static storage?

Comment: @SamuelLi: In C++, automatic storage = non-static locals; static storage = globals and static-anything.  My point was that if there's some way to access the array object itself, especially as part of a struct, then it's possible to have a real problem with strict-aliasing.  If the "array" is just how you're treating some memory you got from `new` or `malloc`, all the `char` accesses to it are going to be via `char*` anyway, and thus aliasing-safe.  But if you have a real  `char array[8]` variable declaration somewhere, access to it might not be through a `char*`.

Comment: @SamuelLi: Although I just realized you can have a problem even with dynamic storage.  If you have `struct foo{ int a; char b[8];};` then you can do struct assignment of the whole struct even via pointers to it, like `foo *p=..., *q=...;` and `*p = *q`.  Access to `char b[8]` is *not* through a `char*` in that case, so a compiler could certainly assume that some `uint64_t*` load or store was unrelated to it.  (You might actually need this struct thing for UB to actually happen, or at least to be a problem in practice, not just a `char arr[8]` local var: `[]` access works by decay to char*)

Comment: @PeterCordes I got it, thanks! I'm convinced that `memcpy` is the safest way to go!

Comment: If you want the low bit of the mask to map to the least significant byte of the uint64_t (the low byte of the bool array on little-endian x86) you need MAGIC = 0x0102040810204080ULL, opposite what you're showing.  See https://godbolt.org/z/j1nGM4TPY which compares test cases for that vs. `pdep` vs. [How to efficiently convert an 8-bit bitmap to array of 0/1 integers with x86 SIMD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52105856).  (For my answer on [Convert 16 bits mask to 16 bytes mask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67203617))

Comment: (The order you have here will give you printing order, MSB at lowest address, on a little-endian machine.   **Opposite of your `pdep` version.**  I found the easiest way to think through which order is which is: `0x...40201 * 0x80` has 0x80 in the low byte, which the mask+shift will turn into `0x...01`.  So high bit of the input maps to low byte of the output, and memcpy into bool[] uses native endianness.)

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/ba8PK99d1 is a test-case for byte-order, giving it `bool a[] = {[7] = 1;}` highest bit set as a test input -> 1 or 0x80.  I made an edit based on sorting all that out, hopefully making this more  usable for future readers.  Note that clang on Godbolt uses host headers, so big-endian targets like powerpc64 still use x86 bits/endianness.h and have backwards `htole64` / `be64`.  (https://github.com/compiler-explorer/compiler-explorer/issues/1469#issuecomment-841416887).  But GCC works, and does sometimes constant-propagate through a bool array init -> memcpy -> multiply.

Comment: The magic number for the LSB->LSB mapping doesn't seem to be correct. The mask 0x80402010 (or a mask 0x01010101...) can work to spread the original byte apart, because the separation of each bit in the mask is at least 8. But in the other multiplier 0x010204....80ull all the bits have a distance of 7 meaning that the input octets overlap. Out of the 256 combinations 64 fail. One cure is to `(a & 0x7f) * magic | (a << 56)`.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen the magic number is correct, you can check the math I posted above. I've also done a [correctness check](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23875535/995714) previously and it works for all 256 combinations. You can also see my edit to see an old implementation with overlap and I had to split out a bit. After I changed to the latest implementation there's zero overlap

Comment: @phuclv: See https://godbolt.org/z/eMfaso3n7, the source copied from the snipped by Peter Cordes. The problem appears in the LSB->LSB conversion, iff  both the LSB and MSB of a byte are set. And thus the magic number can't be simply reversed for big endian architectures. I'm quite sure, the code works for LSB->MSB conversion.

Comment: @AkiSuihkonen the magic number 0x0102040810204080ULL is added by Peter Cordes. My number works for LSB->MSB conversion and you have to reverse endian to make it work for the same direction. I'll edit this when I have time

Comment: When byte-reversing the mask in unpack8bools I cannot get the expected output when b is 255, i.e. every bit is set. `((MAGIC*b) & MASK) >> 7` ends up producing 0x1 instead of 0x101010101010101

Answer (score 12):

You might want to look into [`std::bitset`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset). It allows you to compactly store booleans as bits, with all of the operators you would expect.

No point fooling around with bit-flipping and whatnot when you can abstract away.

Comment: See also [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset).

Answer (score 6):

```
#include <stdint.h>   // to get the uint8_t type

uint8_t GetByteFromBools(const bool eightBools[8])
{
   uint8_t ret = 0;
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++) if (eightBools[i] == true) ret |= (1<<i);
   return ret;
}

void DecodeByteIntoEightBools(uint8_t theByte, bool eightBools[8])
{
   for (int i=0; i<8; i++) eightBools[i] = ((theByte & (1<<i)) != 0);
}
```

Comment: Posting a code solution without any explanation might help OP, but does not provide good value to other users.  You should consider adding comments and/or explain what you did.

Comment: +1 for using uint8_t. Exactly what the type was meant for, when you need exactly 8 bits.

Comment: I hope you realize that `eightBools[i]` is a `bool` and checking it with `== true` you can also just write `(eightBools[i] == true) == true` or `((eightBools[i] == true) == true) == true`, but where to stop? And yes, that's worth not up-voting the answer.

Comment: weltraumpirat I think the code is straightforward enough that a separate explanation would be redundant and only get in the way.  Christian I accept your criticism -- I wouldn't write it like that in my own code -- but I wrote it that way here to make the intent of the code clearer.  You may keep your up-vote, I don't want it ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner You can have it anyway, since you say it's not your practice. Sorry for the harsh words ;)

Comment: @JeremyFriesner For someone who is new to bitmasks, your code isn't straightforward, not one bit (pun intended). I stand by my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2):

```
bool a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;
//do stuff
char y= a<<7 | b<<6 | c<<5 | d<<4 | e <<3 | f<<2 | g<<1 | h;//merge
```

although you are probably better off using a bitset

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/bitset/

Comment: Isn't that too much hardcoding?

Comment: Depends, I wouldn't write it, but if you want to merge 8 separate non contiguous bools then it is the way to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to note that type punning through `union`s is UB in C++ (as *rodrigo* does in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8461163/5958455). The safest way to do that is `memcpy()`

```
struct Bits
{
    unsigned b0:1, b1:1, b2:1, b3:1, b4:1, b5:1, b6:1, b7:1;
};

unsigned char toByte(Bits b){
    unsigned char ret;
    memcpy(&ret, &b, 1);
    return ret;
}
```

As others have said, the compiler is smart enough to optimize out `memcpy()`.

BTW, this is the way that Boost does type punning.

Comment: @Michi Is this question C++?

Comment: Though I like the simplicity of this solution, but it looks like the memory layout of bit fields are compiler dependent [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136426/memory-layout-of-struct-having-bitfields). That is undesired for some use cases...

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to pack 8 `bool` variables into one byte. There is a way packing 8 logical true/false states in a single byte using [Bitmasking](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation).

Comment: You can pack the *values* of 8 `bool`s into one byte.  Of course they're no longer separate C++ `bool` objects, but all 8 values are all there within the bits of one `char` or `uint8_t`.  This answer seems unhelpful and pedantic when the desired behaviour was clear.

Comment: I couldn't read minds as to determine what the intent was, given my crystal ball was broken at the time of answering. I answered the question asked.

Answer (score 0):

You would use the bitwise shift operation and casting to archive it. a function could work like this:

```
unsigned char toByte(bool *bools)
{
    unsigned char byte = \0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; ++i) byte |= ((unsigned char) bools[i]) << i;
    return byte;
}
```

Thanks [Christian Rau](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743214/christian-rau) for the correction **s**!

Comment: I (pst) don't know any C++ ... so if someone could clarify why this question was downvoted, much appreciated!

Comment: Can the people downvoting actually tell me what I am doing wrong? I am naive to programming. :/

Comment: And the reason you use a `short` (which may be 1 byte, but will most probably be 2) and not just a `char` (which is guaranteed to be 1 byte) is...? And also you should use unsigned types and initialize `byte` properly. Fix those and the answer is much more likely to be correct. But I'm not the down-voter, not yet.

Comment: Oh true, I am making the edit now, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: Sorry, i down-voted for multiple misleading mistakes in your answer, which were legendarily explained by Christian Rau, I shall comment next time.

Comment: @fabianhjr Not enough, where is the `unsigned`? And what is that \ for?

Comment: @fabianhjr Also please do change the name of your function.

Comment: @fabianhjr Is there any particular reason to use c cast (unsigned char) here and not cpp ? (just looking at tag)

Comment: Well, it surely will work on both C and C++. Afterall C++ is an extension of C.

Comment: `unsigned char byte = \0;` is invalid. Either use `0` or `'\0'`

Answer (score 0):

`@Fabian` `@111111` -

If you want 8 split out bools with less hard-coding, maybe...

```
bool a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h;      # assuming you want [a] at MSB and 
                           #                   [h] at LSB
```

---

```
char y = a << 7 | b<< 6 | c << 5 | d << 4 | e << 3 | f << 2 | g << 1 | h
```

> 

```
char y = h|(g|(f|(e|(d|(c|(b|a << 1)<< 1)<< 1)<< 1)<< 1)<< 1)<< 1
```

... instead of  7 different shifting amounts, a nested form allow re-using the same shifting constant over and over again,

with the added benefit of placing all the bools/digits together on one side, and all the shifting amounts on the other side

The arithmetic equivalent expressions would be (they're all identical) -

```
char y = h + (g + (f + (e + (d + (c + (b + a * 2) * 2) * 2) * 2) * 2) * 2) * 2

char y = 2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * (2 * a + b) + c) + d) + e) + f) + g) + h

char y = 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * ( 2 * (\
            a ) + b ) + c ) + d ) + e ) + f ) + g ) + h
```

Personally I like the last form the most because it's a full-blown base-conversion routine without requiring the audience to even have any understanding what base and exponents are, or what shifting entails as long as they understand addition and multiplication.