# Bit order from low to high / Mapping structs with bitfields in C

Tags: c, struct, bit-manipulation, bit-fields

I was recently playing around with bit fields in C, and apparently, the bits are ordered from low to high, although Google does not support this thesis (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_numbering).)

Take the following code (http://ideone.com/UwWfJM):

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct bits {
    unsigned char a : 1;
    unsigned char b : 1;
    unsigned char c : 1;
    unsigned char d : 1;
    unsigned char e : 1;
    unsigned char f : 1;
    unsigned char g : 1;
    unsigned char h : 1;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    unsigned char c = 33;
    struct bits *b = (struct bits *) &c;

    printf("dec: %u\n", c);
    printf("bits: %x", b->a);
    printf("%x", b->b);
    printf("%x", b->c);
    printf("%x", b->d);
    printf("%x", b->e);
    printf("%x", b->f);
    printf("%x", b->g);
    printf("%x\n", b->h);

    return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
dec: 33
bits: 10000100
```

...although I had expected the bit ordering to be the other way around (i.e. `00100001`, with the MSB in the first place and the LSB in the last place).

Can somebody explain this behaviour?
Furthermore, can I assume that the mapping will always be in this direction?

*Note:* I am *not* asking about endianness, which is about the *byte* order. The background of my question is that I tried to map a buffer to a struct. The buffer contained a UDP message, consisting of a "bit mapping" (i.e. "bit at position *x* means this, bits at position *y* to *z* mean that, and so on).

Thanks!

Comment: `00100001, with the MSB in the first place and the LSB in the last place` i can't understand this sentence since your `first` and `last` is very ambiguous. could you explain your expectation more in details? btw, pay attention to you printing order, you print `a` first, which yields the first `1`. maybe you misunderstood.

Comment: btw, since your example is using `char` and 8 bit long bit field composition, it indeed has nothing to do with endian. in the struct, `a` represents the lowest bit, which is correct. again, probably you are having a misunderstanding to the printing.

Comment: Well, with `first` and `last` I was referring to the bits shown in the output in a left-to-right reading order. I am well aware that e.g. `b->a` is printed first and outputs `1`. This was the very core of my question (and has already been anwered by @andrew-henle ).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Per 6.7.2.1 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> The order of allocation of bit-fields within a unit (high-order to
>   low-order or low-order to high-order) is implementation-defined.

Comment: Thanks, perfect answer!

Comment: While the order of bit-fields is not defined by the C standard, it is not random. The compiler will assign bits in a well-defined manner *for that compiler and architecture*. However, for best cross-platform compatibility it might be best to avoid bit fields altogether and use "shift and mask" macros instead.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your confusion is in the way you presented the result. You expected it to be printed with the LSB on the right like a normal number, but your code prints a string of bits starting with the LSB on the left and printing to the right.

Your result shows bit `a` in the lowest (first, least significant) memory bit as expected.

Answer (score 0):

The memory layout of bit fields is not defined so its compiler dependent. You can go through[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15136426/memory-layout-of-struct-having-bitfields)

Comment: Thanks! Indeed, I did not find that post before I asked this question!