# Can the char type be categorized as an integer?

Tags: java, c, char

Just now I read "char is the only unsigned integral primitive type in Java."
Does this mean the char is one of the integral types in Java?

Same as in C, recently I have read that C types includes scalar types, function types, union types, aggregate types, and scalar types include pointer types and arithmetic types, then arithmetic types include integral types and floating-point types, the integral types include enumerated types and character types.

Can the char type really be categorized as a integer both in Java and C?

Comment: `char` in java is defined to be a UTF-16 character, which means it is a 2 byte value somewhere between 0 and 65535. This can be easily interpreted as an integer (the math concept, not `int`). `char` in c is defined to be a 1 byte character somewhere between 0 and 255.

Comment: @HansZ Although `CHAR_BIT == 8` is by far the most common, the C standard allows larger values. There even are a few implementations with 32-bit `char`s, iirc.

Comment: @DanielFischer Ansi C standard (C99) $2.2.4.2:

 * maximum number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte) 
CHAR_BIT                         8 

 * minimum value for an object of type signed char 
SCHAR_MIN                     -127 

 * maximum value for an object of type signed char 
SCHAR_MAX                     +127 

 * maximum value for an object of type unsigned char 
UCHAR_MAX                      255

Comment: @DanielFischer full text: http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt

Comment: @HansZ "Their implementation-deﬁned values shall be equal or greater in magnitude (absolute value) to those shown, with the same sign."

Comment: @DanielFischer maximum number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte) CHAR_BIT 8

Comment: @HansZ The given value 8 is the **minimum** allowed value for `CHAR_BIT`. An implementation may give it a greater value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, a `char` is an integral type in all the popular languages in which it appears. "Integral" means that its spectrum is discrete and the smallest difference between any two distinct values is `1`. The required range of supported values is usually quite small compared to that of other integral types. Computer hardware traditionally treats integers as the fundamental data type; by contrast, arithmetic floating-point types are a more recent and more complicated addition.

Comment: Or a type `T` is an integer type if the value of an object of type `T` is an integer.

Comment: @ouah: Hm. Is `'a'` an integer? :-)

Comment: @KerrekSB In C, it's even an `int`.

Comment: @KerrekSB (C99, 6.4.4.4p10) "**The value of an integer character constant** containing a single character that maps to a single-byte execution character **is the numerical value of the representation of the mapped character interpreted as an integer**." It stands OK with my definition ;)

Comment: no, char in Pascal, which is also a popular language (although not common like the old days), is not an integral type. You'll have to use ord() and chr() to convert between characters and its value

Comment: @LưuVĩnhPhúc: OK -- but it's still discrete, although it isn't *arithmetic*, and so the notion of "difference between two values" may not be defined...

Answer (score 5):

According to the Java [Primitive Data Types](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) tutorial:

> **char**: The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character. It has a minimum value of '\u0000' (or 0) and a maximum value of '\uffff' (or 65,535 inclusive).

So yes, it is a 16-bit unsigned integer. Whether you use the type to represent a number or a character is up to you...

---

Also keep in mind that while the `char` type is guaranteed to be 16 bits in Java, the only restriction C imposes is that the type must be at least 8 bits. According to the C spec reference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881894/is-char-guaranteed-to-be-exactly-8-bit-long-in-c):

> maximum number of bits for smallest object that is not a bit-field (byte)
>
> CHAR_BIT 8

So a `char` in C does not necessarily represent the same range of integer values as a `char` in Java.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to @aioobe's answer

```
int n = 5;
char ch = (char) '0' + 5; // '5'
```

or the reverse

```
char ch = '9';
int i = ch - '0'; // 9
```

or the unusual

```
char ch = 'a';
ch += 1; // 'b';
```

or the odd

```
char ch = '0';
ch *= 1.1; // '4' as (char) (48 * 1.1) == '4'

ch %= 16; // `\u0004`
int i = ch; // 4
```

BTW: From String.hashCode()

```
// int h = 0;
char val[] = value;
int len = count;

for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    h = 31*h + val[off++];
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm unsure of the formal definition of an *integral type*, but in short, yes, `char` is an integral type in Java, since it can be seen as representing an integer.

You can for instance do

```
char c1 = 'a' + 'b';

char c2 = 5;

char c3 = c2 + 3;

int i = c3;
char c4 = (char) i;
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1):

In memory, essentially everything is integral... but yes. char is an integer type in C, C++ and Java.

Answer (score 1):

Char is an "Integer Data Type" in C and its related progeny. As per the K&R Book, "By definition, chars are just small integers". They are used for storing 'Character' data.

The ASCII Table lists 128 characters, and each text character corresponds to an integer value.

Char Data Type is a 1 Byte (8 Bits). Therefore, they can store upto 2^8 = 256 different integers. (These 256 different integers correspond to different ASCII or UTF characters.)

For example:

As per ASCII standard, the letter "x" is stored as 01111000 (decimal 120).

for e.g., you can Add a value in a char variable, just like any integer!

```
int main()
{
    char a='x';
    int b=3+a;
    printf("value is:\n%d",b);
    return 0;
 }
```

output: b=123 (3 + 120 for the char 'x')

i.e. chars are just numbers (integers: 0-256 (unsigned)).

Answer (score 0):

The C specification calls for the **char** type to be implemented as a 1-byte integer.  The specifications for other types are not always so clear.  For example, the original Kernigan and Ritchie C book said that, as far as **short** and **long** were concerned, among different implementations, you could only rely on the fact that **short** was no longer than **long**.

Comment: `char` in java is UTF-16, meaning it is a two byte character. `char` in c is defined such that `sizeof(char)` always yields 1, meaning it is necessarily a 1 byte value.

Comment: UTF-16 is only two bytes on machines where a byte is 8 bits. Byte is architecture dependent.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes a char type can be categorized as an integer:**

```
int i = 49;
int k = 36;

System.out.print((char)i + (char)k + "$"); //may expect 1$ but print: 85$
```

Comment: Dont except 1$ because char cant be add up