# how to convert char to int in c?

Tags: c, variables, char, int

I was trying to make a program which was to much big for a noob like. it was approximatly 100 line(for noob like me,its big).But every time i run its loops aren't ending.So dicided to compile and check small parts of the code and I get bingo in fist part.here is that part

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){//B main
    int cha,z; 
    printf("enter the alphabte in capital until you want the alphabats :-  ");
    scanf("%c",&z);
    for(;z>=65;z--)
        for(cha=65;cha<=z;cha++)
        {  
            if(cha!=z)
                printf("%c ",cha);
            else
                printf("%c \n",cha);
        }
}//B main
```

.I have modified it it and if i enter c it should give an output like this:-

```
A B C
A B
A
```

But the loop does not ends and i keep getting something like this on terminal

```
              ! " # $ % & ' ( ) * + , - . / 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 : ; < = > ? @ A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z [ \ ] ^ _ ` a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z { | } ~  � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
```

thus try this part

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 int main(){
     int a;
     scanf("%d",&a);
     printf("%d",a);
 }
```

If I enter A then it should give me 65 as an output as A's ASCII value is 65 but it gives me following output

```
32766
```

but my this program give me correct ASCII values

```
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

  int main(){
      int b,c;
      b=0;
      printf("\n these are ASCII values of all letters \n\n\n ");
      while(b<=255)
      {
           printf("%c %d \n",b,b);
           b=b+1;
      }
 }
```

#### How can I use characters like `a A G j` as integers with there ASCII values?

#### How can I do arithmetic operations with their ASCII values?

Comment: Please try to reorganize the question. It is extremely difficult to understand what you are even asking.

Comment: `%c` expects a character as parameter, not an integer.

Comment: **Always** check return value of `scanf`.

Comment: Read this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11698535/is-char-a-special-type-of-integer-variable

Comment: With `scanf("%d",&a);` you ask to read an *integer* value, not a character. If you check what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) returns then it would be zero meaning it didn't read anything. That leaves `a` *uninitialized* with an *indeterminate* value.

Comment: For your first program, use a *debugger* to step through your code, line by line, to see what it does.

Comment: Also for your first program, what *is* the input you give it?

Comment: Lastly, don't use [*magic numbers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). If you with `65` mean the character `'A'` then use the character instead. And note that not all platforms use [ASCII](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/ascii).

Comment: @TonyTannous I have declared explicitly my questions in bold.please read it.thanks

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your second code should be:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
       char a;
       scanf("%c", &a); // read in single character value
       printf("%d",a); 
 }
```

Some other notes:

- You can use literal chars instead of the values in your code: 
  `if (char == 'A'){ printf("char is 'A'");}`
- You can add and subtract like normal values:
  `printf("%d", 'C' - 'A');` prints `2`
- I just ran your first code snippet.  It works fine for me.

This is the output:

```
$ ./a.exe
enter the alphabte in capital until you want the alphabats :-  C
A B C
A B
A
```

Comment: In your original code, you chould change your z variable to char type and it will work.

Comment: I agree with you that the best way is to explicity cast to int type.

Comment: You are correct, it will get promoted. I will remove the comments.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, change it to use `%c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char a;
  scanf("%c",&a);
  printf("%d",a);
}
```

Put in 'A' and it prints 65 as expected.

Now just expand that for your code.  Oh and check the return value of `scanf`. I didn't here because I wanted to keep the example simple, but always do it in actual code.

Comment: His question is:  "how can i use characters like `A` `G` and use them as integers with their ASCII values ?".

Comment: the integer value will be stored in `a`.  If 'A' is provided, `a` will have the value `65` and it can be used as if it were an int in sums.

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya *there is no promotion since `printf` doesn't have a type for the second argument* No.  See **6.5.2.2 Function calls** of [the C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf): "The  ellipsis  notation  in  a  function  prototype  declarator  causes
argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter.  **The default argument
promotions are performed on trailing arguments**."

Comment: @AjayBrahmakshatriya so it gets promoted.  where is the problem?

Comment: @AndrewHenle you are correct. They will be promoted. I will remove my comments.

Comment: @Baldrickk please my question again.I had edited it.and why my ASCII finder program is working?please.i am waiting for your answer.and thanks for answering.I really appreciate that.

Answer (score 0):

Provide your own set of valid characters.
Use `strchr` to see if the input is in the set of valid characters. If not, try again for correct input.
Once correct input is obtained, use `strchr` again to make sure the incremented and decremented values remain valid.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void) {
    char valid[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char z = valid[0];
    char cha = valid[0];
    char *ok = NULL;
    char *chaok = NULL;

    printf("enter the alphabte in capital until you want the alphabats :-  ");
    do {
        if ( 1 != scanf(" %c",&z)) {
            fprintf ( stderr, "problem with input\n");
            return 0;
        }
        ok = strchr ( valid, z);
        if ( !ok) {
            printf ( "enter an uppercase letter. try again\n");
        }
    } while ( !ok);

    while ( ( ok = strchr ( valid, z)) && ok >= valid) {
        cha = valid[0];
        while ( ( chaok = strchr ( valid, cha)) && chaok <= ok) {
            if( chaok != ok)
                printf("%c ",cha);
            else
                printf("%c \n",cha);
            cha = *(++chaok);
        }
        z = 0x1;
        if ( ok > valid) {
            z = *(ok - 1);
        }
    }
}
```