# Why does 88 represent the character code of 'X'?

Tags: java, char

Here is a program that demonstrates char variables:

```
// Demonstrate char data type.
class CharDemo {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        char ch1, ch2; 

        ch1 = 88; // code for X
        ch2 = 'Y'; 

        System.out.print("ch1 and ch2: ");
        System.out.println(ch1 + " " + ch2);
    }
}
```

This program displays the following output:

> ch1 and ch2: X Y

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding: [0x58 Latin Capital Letter X](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0058)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671908/can-the-char-type-be-categorized-as-an-integer

Answer (score 2):

`char`s are just smaller integers with fancy formatting. 88 happens to be [the unicode value of X](http://www.codetable.net/decimal/88), so when you store it in a `char`, it would be printed that way.

Comment: It happens to also be the ASCII code of X, but in general the "small integer" in a Java `char` is a Unicode code point (the first 127 of those are shared with ASCII).