# How do I correctly print this triangle of characters?

Tags: java, character, ascii

This code asks the user for a triangle height and a letter.

```
import java.util.*;
public class triangle
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = 0;
        Character c;

        System.out.println("Enter height of the triangle : ");
        size = kb.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Which character you want to use : ");
        c = kb.next().charAt(0);

        int i, j, k;

        for (i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = size; j > i; j--) 
            {
                System.out.print(" ");
            }
            for (k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++) 
            {
                System.out.print(c);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

For a height of 3 and the letter `b`, current output is:

```
  b
 bbb
bbbbb
```

But it should be:

```
  b
 cbc
dcbcd
```

How can I print letters in the alphabet *after* the given letter in the triangle pattern shown above?

Comment: Might wanna think about what to do if the user inputs a `z` , and as a hint you should probably use `ascii` to get the letter after.

Comment: `System.out.print(c);` this is always going to print the letter the user inputted. If you need to print a different letter, you're going to have to do something different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Your problem

Let's talk about your variable `c`, which is a `char`. (Actually, `c` is a [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Character.html), the boxed equivalent of a `char`, but that doesn't matter too much.)

In Java, [`char` is a number type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11671908/can-the-char-type-be-categorized-as-an-integer). All `char`s are numbers. For example, the `char` literal `'a'` is actually the number 97:

```java
'a' == 97; // true
```

And you can do arithmetic with `char`, just as you can with regular numbers:

```java
'a' + 1; // 98
'a' + 2; // 99
'a' + 3; // 100
```

The mapping between characters like `'a'` and numbers like 97 in Java follows the universal standard [Unicode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode), a superset of the older standard [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII). In other words, `'a' == 97` because ASCII says so. Here's an ASCII table:

[image]

Both ASCII and Java's `char` were thoughtfully designed so that doing arithmetic with characters works exactly like you'd expect. Study these examples:

```java
(char) ('a' + 1); // 'b'
(char) ('a' + 2); // 'c'
(char) ('a' + 3); // 'd'
```

As you see, in the last line, adding 3 to `'a'` and then converting it back to a `char` produces `'d'`, which is 3 letters after `'a'`.

So if you want x letters after some character `c`, the code is just `(char) (c + x)`.

In your case, for each letter you print in the triangle, you want to increase the user's character (in your example, `'b'`) by the letter-to-print's distance from the central letter. The letter-to-print is in position `k`, and central letter is always in position `i - 1`; thus the distance is `Math.abs(k - (i - 1))`, or `Math.abs(k - i + 1)`. That's how much to add to the character.

With this knowledge, it's simple to fix your code. Replace:

```java
for (k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++) 
{
    System.out.print(c);
}
```

with:

```java
for (k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++) 
{
    System.out.print((char) (c + Math.abs(k - i + 1)));
}
```

## Other problems

While you're here, you may as well fix some other issues with your code:

1. In Java, it's convention for classes to begin with a capital letter. This means you should change:

   ```java
   public class triangle
   {
   ```

   to:

   ```java
   public class Triangle
   {
   ```

   and rename `triangle.java` to `Triangle.java`.
2. You don't need to declare variables at the top. It's better to declare them when you first need them, allowing you to combine the declaration and initial assignment. For instance, instead of:

   ```java
   int size = 0;
   // ...
   size = kb.nextInt();
   ```

   You can simply write:

   ```java
   int size = kb.nextInt();
   ```

   Here's your code, refactored to fix this:

   ```java
   Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);

   System.out.println("Enter height of the triangle : ");
   int size = kb.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Which character you want to use : ");
   Character c = kb.next().charAt(0);

   for (int i = 0; i < size + 1; i++)
   {
       for (int j = size; j > i; j--)
       {
           System.out.print(" ");
       }
       for (int k = 0; k < (2 * i - 1); k++)
       {
           System.out.print((char) (c + Math.abs(k - i + 1)));
       }
       System.out.println();
   }
   ```
3. You should use `char`, not `Character`, for `c`. `Character` should only be used if you need to deal with [boxing and unboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/autoboxing.html) (e.g. you want to define an `ArrayList<Character>`), which has nothing to do with your current problem. So replace:

   ```java
   Character c = kb.next().charAt(0);
   ```

   with:

   ```java
   char c = kb.next().charAt(0);
   ```
4. Use `System.out.print()` for prompts. It allows the user to type the answer on the same line. Instead of:

   ```java
   System.out.println("Enter height of the triangle : ");
   int size = kb.nextInt();

   System.out.println("Which character you want to use : ");
   char c = kb.next().charAt(0);
   ```

   Use:

   ```java
   System.out.print("Enter height of the triangle: ");
   int size = kb.nextInt();

   System.out.print("Enter character you want to use: ");
   char c = kb.next().charAt(0);
   ```

Comment: thank you not for the answer, for the great advice!! no one tell me about any of them before.