# what is the meaning when put char into a int array ,is it ASC number?

Tags: java

```
class Solution {
public boolean isIsomorphic(String s, String t) {
    
    int [] index_s = new int [128];//创建两个int数组128位，里面的值都为0
    int [] index_t = new int [128];
    
    for (int i =0; i<s.length(); i++){
        char sc = s.charAt(i); //取每一个位置上的字符
        char tc = t.charAt(i);
        
        if (index_s[sc] != index_t[tc]){
            return false ;
        }else{
            index_s[sc]=i+1;
            index_t[tc]=i+1;
        }
        
    }
    return true ;
    
    
}
}
```

from the code above, in the int array , sc and tc are char variables, so what is the meaning of this code ?

Comment: both arrays `index_s` and `index_t` are of length 128 which is equal to the ascii table. When you do `charAt()`, you will get the character at a specific index, for example `a`. Then when you do `index_s[sc]`, the char will be converted to it's int representation in the ascii table, so `a` is 97.

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

Your code counts the number of occurrences where the nth character in both input strings match, sharing the same US-ASCII number (Unicode code point number). The count is kept in an array where the indexes represent all the 128 possible US-ASCII code numbers (0-127). The code uses a trick of sorts, where the `char` type in Java is effectively a 16-bit integer number.

Your code works for input `String` objects whose values contain only US-ASCII characters. Your code fails if the inputs contain any of the other 143,731 characters defined in Unicode.

## Details

As [commented by Haddad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68155833/what-is-the-meaning-when-put-char-into-a-int-array-is-it-asc-number#comment120458483_68155833), your lines fragments:

```
index_s[sc]
index_t[tc]
```

… are using variables `sc` and `tc`, both of type `char` as though they are integers. Those integer values are used as zero-based index numbers into the array to access a slot. This works because in Java, the `char` type is treated as an integer number. For a discussion of this peculiar language feature, see [*Can the char type be categorized as an integer?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11671908/642706).

The Unicode [code point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepoint) number (same as [US-ASCII](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) numbers for the first 128, as Unicode is a superset of US-ASCII) is the numeric value extracted from each `char`. The letter `a` as a `char` is effectively a 97 decimal integer number, the `char` value of `b` is 98, and so on.

Your code then goes on to increment the `int` value in that slot of the array. The array of `int` primitive type is automatically initialized to zero in every slot. Your calls to `=i+1` increments that slot’s number, going from 0 to 1, then 1 to 2, and so on. This incrementing in your code is a count of how often we encounter that code point number in the input strings.

The US-ASCII numbers are zero-based, running 0-127. Array indexes in Java are also zero-based. So no need to adjust. The `NUL` character assigned to US-ASCII number `0` will be counted in the array slot accessed using an index of `0`.

Your code:

```java
if (index_s[sc] != index_t[tc]){
            return false ;
```

… skips over cases where the nth character in both input strings is the same character, as the same code point number.

The last line makes no sense: `return true ;`. Always returning `true` serves no useful purpose.

By the way, the `char` type is now obsolete, unable to represent even half of the characters defined in Unicode. You should instead learn to work only with the Unicode code points directly as `int` rather than `char`.

Comment: Actually, it is a code unit not a code point in this case.  Either way, it is difficult to understand what this code (as written) really *means*, but it is not going to deal with Unicode correctly.  (It will throw an exception if the strings contain non-ASCII characters.)