# Do the ASCII values change if I declare signed char?

Tags: c++, c++11

If I declare `signed char k = 'a'` then will the value of `k` not be 97, which is the ASCII value of 'a', as the range of `signed char` is -128 to 127?

If not then what does it mean by range of `signed char`?

Comment: Can't you check this with a trivial program?

Comment: `97` is within the range of -128 to 127

Comment: Not only is @MattMcNabb correct, but *every* ASCII character is in the range 0 to 127. There are other character sets that are supersets of ASCII where it might be a problem though.

Answer (score 0):

Why would a value suddenly change? The ASCII table is a list of constants, and `'a'` always matches 97 in any language/environment that conforms to the ASCII-standards (so more or less all of them).

The *range* consists of the minimum and maximum value that can be contained in a variable of a given type.

A `signed char` has 8 bits of which 1 for the sign, meaning 7 bits of actual data and it can be positive or negative. Therefore it can contain integer values between -128 and 127.

An `unsigned char` has 8 bits, all for actual data, meaning it can contain integer values between 0 and 255.

---

(the above is naively assuming a modern system in which a `char` contains 8 bits, it [could theoretically be more](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881968/1729885). Also, as explained in that link, the bottom limit of a `signed char` could also be -127 on your specific system - use `limits.h` to be sure)

Comment: What do you mean by " (ie. all of them)." ? There are non-ASCII systems (although IDK if any non-ASCII system ever had an ISO C++ compliant compiler)

Comment: @MattMcNabb with enough users to be practical for the purposes of this answer? That's about as likely as running into the system where a `char` actually has 10 bits.

Comment: well if you're going to mention one corner case maybe mention them all..:) it's also theoretically possible that `signed char` will use one's complement or sign-magnitude in which case the minimum value would be `-127`. (But again I don't know if anyone ever did that for C++, although they certainly did for C)

Comment: Well I changed it to 'more or less all of them' now, should make the nitpickers happy  :P

Comment: IBM has a C++ compiler for zOS (which was the reason for not removing trigraphs)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're asking, but the C++ standard promises that all of the characters in the basic execution character set will be non-negative. From C++11 2.3/3 :

> For each basic execution character set, the values of the members
>   shall be non-negative and distinct from one another

The basic execution character set is the 26 letters (upper and lower case) a-z and A-Z, the digits 0-9, most the set of punctuation marks that are in the ASCII character set (for example, '$' and '@' are not included) as well as space and a few core control characters.

However, other characters might have a negative representation when `signed char` is used. For example, in one possible code page the Euro character, '€', has a value of 128 if `char` is unsigned, but a value of -128 if `char` is signed.

Comment: Was that quote in C++03? It excludes EBCDIC systems with signed char.

Comment: Yes, C++03 says the same thing. I haven't used EBCDIC systems, but a glance at Wikipedia's table makes it look like unsigned char or a `char` type with more than 8 bits would be needed to comply with that requirement. A point of interest - the C standard (up through C11) does *not* require that these values be non-negative. I'm a little surprised at the difference in this detail between C and C++, but not a whole lot.  Is EBCDIC more than a historical curiosity anymore?

Comment: @MichaelBurr This is wrong. ISO C99 says in 6.2.5p3: "If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative." Thus it has the same requirement as C++03. This means that an EBCDIC implementation must have `char` behaving like `unsigned char`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45123003/do-a-and-0-always-have-positive-values-even-if-char-is-signed