# C++ sizeof integral types

Tags: c++

I have heard from books, presentation about minimal size for integral types in C/C++

Sizes below are in bytes:

- `sizeof(char) >= 1`
- `sizeof(short) >= 2`
- `sizeof(long) >= 4`
- `sizeof(long long) >= 8`

But I cannot find those guarantees in standards.
So are there any guarantees required by compilers to implement defined in standards C++98 / C++2003 / C89 / C99?

Comment: You may find your answer here: [Does the size of an int depend on the compiler and/or processor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2331751/does-the-size-of-an-int-depend-on-the-compiler-and-or-processor)

Comment: sizeof(char) always returns 1. I guess your numbers mean bits.

Comment: I made some fixies to question. I was more interesting in what standard said

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does the C++ standard state the size of int, long type to be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be)

Comment: Thanks, But I'm not interesting in msdn or smth. like http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types I'm only interesting in what said C|C++ standarts http://port70.net/~nsz/c/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there are none. Standard defines only some basic guarantees and requirements regarding values. You can find them [in this document](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) on page 33:

**5.2.4.2.1 Sizes of integer types .**

You can be sure, that:

```
sizeof(char) ≤ sizeof(short) ≤ sizeof(int) ≤ sizeof(long) ≤ sizeof(long long)
```

and

```
sizeof(float) ≤ sizeof(double) ≤ sizeof(long double)
```

Also:

- `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be 1
- `sizeof(char) == sizeof(signed char) == sizeof(unsigned char)`

Also, on most platforms:

- `sizeof(char) = 1`
- `sizeof(short) = 2`
- `sizeof(int) = 4`
- `sizeof(long) = 4`
- `sizeof(long long) = 8` `(1)`

---

(1) `long long` is not a standard type. GCC and VC++ have supported it for a long time now, but official support came with C++ 11:

[C++: Fundamental Types](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types)

> `long long` - target type will have width of at least 64 bits. *(since C++11)*

Note, that even if `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`, it doesn't mean, that `char` is 8 bit long. `CHAR_BIT` defines number of bits in `char` type. These days, almost all architectures use 8 bits per byte, but some older architectures used to have 7.

Comment: Thanks. By the way I check standard and I couldn't found it in C++2003, but I found it in C99 standard http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c99/C99RationaleV5.10.pdf, page 38 "C99 has therefore adopted long long as the name of an integer type with at least 64 bits of
precision"

Comment: @bruzzo This question was eplicitly marked as `c++`, so answer was C++-specific - until C++ 11 there was no such thing like `long long`. Also, some compilers may not support C99, even if they support even the newest C++ standards (like MSVC - Microsoft cares only about those C features, that seem necessary for them - VS 2012 lacked in support for C99 almost totally, I don't know if (and how) that was changed with newer versions).

Comment: You're right I tagged question only with c++,...but I wrote about other c++ friends in the tail of the question

Comment: I tried to compile main_c99.c with vc compiler from visual studio 2012 gui environment:...
int main()
{
    int x[] = {[1]=2};
    return sizeof(x);
} -- it failed) Then I try to find some flag that will be similar to gcc -std=c99 main_c99.c

Comment: I didn't find anything in compiler/linker page in visual studio 2015 page...So It seems that Microsoft was not really interesting in support of c99)

Answer (score 6):

That's not correct, your values are multiplied by 8. (Note that a sizeof 1 doesn't necessarily mean 8 bits, the number of bits in a char is `CHAR_BIT` - most likely 8 though).

The `sizeof(char)` is guaranteed to be `1`. (as well as `unsigned char` and `signed char`).

Other than that,

> The result of sizeof applied to any other fundamental type (3.9.1) is
>   implementation-defined. **(5.3.3 Sizeof)**

There are ordering restrictions along the lines of `sizeof(char) <= sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long long)`.

Comment: Thanks. I should have read chapter 5.3.3 before post question, and retrieveing minus to it.

Answer (score 2):

Here what `The C++ Programming Language Fourth Edition by Bjarne Stroustrup` says about the matter.

Sizes of C++ objects are expressed in terms of multiples of the size of a `char`, so by definition the size of a `char` is 1.

```
• 1 ≡ sizeof(char) ≤ sizeof(short) ≤ sizeof(int) ≤ sizeof(long) ≤ sizeof(long long)
• 1 ≤ sizeof(bool) ≤ sizeof(long)
• sizeof(char) ≤ sizeof(wchar_t) ≤ sizeof(long)
• sizeof(float) ≤ sizeof(double) ≤ sizeof(long double)
• sizeof(N) ≡ sizeof(signed N) ≡ sizeof(unsigned N)
```

In that last line, `N` can be `char`, `short`, `int`, `long`, or `long long`. In addition, it is guaranteed that a `char` has at least 8 bits, a `short` at least 16 bits, and a `long` at least 32 bits

Comment: "In addition, it is guaranteed that a char has at least 8 bits, a short at least 16 bits, and a long at least 32 bits". I can't find it in standart.

Comment: [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/589575/what-does-the-c-standard-state-the-size-of-int-long-type-to-be/589684#589684) or [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types) re size of C++ types.

Comment: @bruzzo, same information given [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/variables/)

Comment: @bruzzo, In addition [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881894/is-char-guaranteed-to-be-exactly-8-bit-long) one answer explains the matter in C standard and the other one refers to C++ standard.