# In Java,how to simulate "converting negative numbers casted by unsigned char in c"?

Tags: java, c, int, bitwise-operators, unsigned-char

for example, in c, converting -1234 to unsigned char would become 46:

```
int main(){
    int a=-1234;
    unsigned char b=a;
    printf("%d\n",b);
    return 0;
};
```

I want to convert the code to java version, now the code is:

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int a=-1234;
        int b=(a%(Byte.MAX_VALUE-Byte.MIN_VALUE+1))+(a<0?(Byte.MAX_VALUE-Byte.MIN_VALUE+1):0);
        System.out.println(b);
    }
}
```

Is there any faster (or simpler) way to do this (e.g.:bitwise operation)?

Comment: A char is a 16bit data type. Why are you using byte? Also, I think your c example conversion is undefined and will have different results for different integer representations.

Comment: What's up with that weird code? It's just `b = a & 0xFF`

Comment: Note that `unsigned char` isn't guaranteed to be any particular size.

Comment: @matt, it isn't (in C). [discussion on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881894/is-char-guaranteed-to-be-exactly-8-bit-long). It is guaranteed to be one byte. It will be 16 bit long, if one byte on your machine is 16 bits long. But it is a weird machine you have.

Comment: @FreeNickname Sorry, I was refering to java. A [java char](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.1) is 16 bits. That was my second point though, that the casting that OP is asking about is not uniquely defined.

Comment: In case you missed the implications of my previous comment, it means the conversion is not guaranteed to yield `46`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int a = -1234;

a = (byte) a & 0xFF;
System.out.println(a); 
//Output: 46
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't simulate, it is called casting.

```
char a = (char)-1234;
byte b = (byte)-1234;
int unsigned = b>=0?b:128 - b;
System.out.println((int)a + ", " + Byte.toUnsignedInt(b) + ", " + unsigned);
//output
//64302, 46, 46
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int a = -1234;
    byte b = a < 0 ? (byte) -((byte) ((a ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1)) : (byte)a;

    System.out.println(b);
```

Comment: `(a ^ 0xFFFFFFFF) + 1` is a funny way of writing `-a`

Comment: I just wanted to show what exactly hides behind "-" (negative) operation. That's not nice that unsigned primitives are not supported by java